# "Established user" privilege has an inaccurate description

Tags: feature-request, privileges

[This description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) isn't really accurate.

> Established users are those who have been participating on the site for a fair amount of time.

It's possible for a user to achieve this privilege in well under a year, before the user has even acquired their Yearling badge. Attaining reputation of one thousand on StackOverflow in particular doesn't actually reflect how long the user has "been around" (Some users have probably achieved the prerequisite score in a matter of weeks, depending on the exchange site).

I propose a change of wording to something along the lines of:

> You're an established user; see vote counts.

Comment: Should I move this to Meta?

Comment: You did ask it on meta.  This is the right place to ask, but some people are probably disagreeing with your feature request.

Comment: Even a month is "been around for a while"

Comment: I meant the Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ouflak if someone feels it needs to be there, it will be moved.  Asking on a site meta is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Magisch, if that were true, then the badge wouldn't depend on reputation. After a month, every user would get the privilege. That's clearly not what is intended. But the wording doesn't reflect what you've said.

Comment: @ouflak my point is "around for a while" is unspecified. The 1000 rep you need is specific.

Comment: It's specific to rep, not to time that the user has actually 'been around', and thus the description is inaccurate.

Comment: Don't you think that 1000 rep is time enough to "be around" for a while?

Comment: It really depends. Depending on the popularity of a topic and the traffic that a site gets, 10 - 20 good answers in a month could earn somebody the privilege. And 1000 is specific to StackOverflow. Other exchange sites have other requirements. On some sites, it will be difficult to attain the privilege no matter how long the user has been around or how active (and positively contributing) they've been. Hence I think the change is valid. The current wording is not actually related to how long the user has been around, it's related to rep.

Comment: @ouflak strictly speaking you can earn it in 5 days after joining.

Comment: @Magisch, you help make my point. Would you mind throwing me an upvote? ;--)

Comment: @ouflak I dont particularly think the change is necessary though, I think thats just mainly nitpicking. I got that thing yesterday, and its about 23 days after joining and only 3 weeks of contributing actively. But I don't think the description matters alot in this context.

Comment: @Magisch. Fair enough. But my point stands.

Comment: @Magisch You could technically earn it faster. You just need someone to give you a couple 500 rep bounties.

Comment: @ouflak I didn't downvote your question, if thats what you mean.

Comment: @resueman I mean realisticly speaking. A person who wants to and has enough time on their hands should have no problem hitting the rep cap every day.

Comment: _"And 1000 is specific to StackOverflow."_ Where did you see that exactly? The other sites I've been on also have "Established User" set at 1000 rep. As far as I understand, only beta sites have lower privilege limits, and that is just so they can start building up users with moderation privileges faster.

Comment: Well extreme situations aside, yes it is theoretically possible that a sharp user with excellent timing and with some bounty assistance could get the privilege darn near instantly. I was however thinking more along the lines of more typical use. There are plenty of realistic scenarios where the wording isn't really correct.

Comment: @Kendra, Expatriates and History of Science and Mathematics, it's 750.

Comment: @ouflak there are 2 thresholds "Beta sites" and "Established sites".  Beta sites have different rep limits because they have few users with high rep to help with community moderation.

Comment: @ouflak Yeah, just looked- That's a beta site. So as I said, only beta sites have lower privilege requirements.

Comment: I think the description that's there is just looking to avoid being redundant. The title of the privilege already says "Established User". It wouldn't really be explaining what that means if the description for it just repeats "established user".

Comment: @psubsee2003, Good to know. My point of my original post still stands, especially with the knowledge that some tags and sites are far more visited and trafficked than others. Points, and the privilege, can come real fast for some users who are around for only a brief period to time. For others who regularly participate over long periods, maybe years, they might never get the privilege.. The wording should be changed.

Comment: @BSMP, Good point. I'm open to wording suggestions.

Comment: meh, I don't see the need.  As @BSMP mentioned, you should define something by using that word in the defintion.  Say you are an established user because you are an established user is a poor description.

Comment: @psubsee2003. I agree. The current wording is inaccurate. My suggestion is redundant. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like a very long argument about a purposefully vague description. How long **is** *"a fair amount of time"*, then?

Comment: @I'd say atleast as long as a Yearling badge takes to achieve. Maybe my question is really the wrong question. Maybe it isn't the wording of the privilege that should be changed, maybe it's the prerequisites.... Can that be done with privileges?

Comment: The point of "a fair amount of time" is, really, that you've been on the site long enough to get some idea of how the site _works_.

Comment: @Joe, then why does it depend on rep? Somebody could be around for years, contribute and take part positively, know very well how the site(s) works, and never get the privilege. Heck in theory, if a user has read the tour and help, they know how the site works.

Comment: Well, it depends on rep because that's just about the only slightly useful way to measure participation, even though it's extremely inaccurate. (Remember that there's positive participation, negative participation, neutral participation and just looking on.)

Comment: @Deduplicator, which leads me to aks again if I'm asking the right question. Afterall, there is a badge which is tied to the time a user is actually a member of the site along with their reputation. So there is precedent, atleast with the badges. Maybe it isn't the description that needs to change. Maybe it's the prerequisites for the privilege.

Comment: @ouflak There are certainly plenty of examples of people - hichris for example, for a while - who clearly knew a lot about the site without really contributing much on the main site (rather via meta and chat participation).  But that's the exception to the rule; the far majority of people get familiar with the site _by_ participating, so it's a reasonable ruler for site familiarity.  It's not perfect, but in a site of hundreds of thousands of users, you're not going to find a perfect ruler.

Comment: How about *"you seem to be doing OK so far; how about we give you some more stuff and see if you can manage to not screw things up too badly?"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe: If that isn't a ringing endorsement ;-)

Comment: @Joe, but the example you use is a person who is 'participating'. And tags/sites with lower traffic might see a user ask/answer hundreds of high quality questions and never come close to the privilege.

(At) jonrsharpe, :-) That sounds like a description more apt to a first moderation privilege.

Comment: @ouflak Sure, nobody said it's perfect.  It's just how it is.  But I managed to do pretty well almost entirely in a single tag with low traffic, so it seems to work well enough.  Hundreds of high quality questions, you're still going to get 10-15 points per question even in the lowest traffic tags, so you'll hit your couple thousand.  And if it's a zero-traffic tag, well, such is life.

Comment: *Maybe it isn't the wording of the privilege that should be changed, maybe it's the prerequisites.* - Why? Is there some problem with just basing it on rep?

Comment: @BSMP, No problem at all. I just have a problem with the wording. Just wondering out loud, because of the responses here, if I'm thinking about it wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The current privilege description already provides an accurate explanation of the word "established". That's as accurate as it needs to be.

The reputation milestone is just a means to that end, in a privilege system that operates solely on reputation milestones. It's not supposed to be the be-all and end-all of what it means *to* establish oneself in a community.

Comment: @ouflak: Whose idea was it to end both words with a -ge?!

Comment: Not asking for perfection in the reputation system. Just accuracy with regards to the description of one privilege. I'm picky like that, hence the style and thoroughness of my edits.

Comment: "The reputation milestone is just a means to that end, in a privilege system that operates solely on reputation milestones. It's not supposed to be the be-all and end-all of what it means to establish oneself in a community" - I agree completely. Hence my suggestion that the wording be changed.