# How can we stop failing the users who we actually want to join, and remain as, members of our community?

Tags: discussion, new-users, welcoming

For context, please read [this excellent answer by Scratte, one of the very users this question is concerned with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394890/70345).

What was your reaction to that answer? Sadness? Shame? Despair? Because those were the emotions that I went through, reading an account of an experience that has been so utterly miserable that they, in their own words, "stopped providing Answers" and "have lots of Questions, but [they] don't ask them".

We, the users of Meta - for want of a better term, the Stack Overflow community - know that Stack Exchange Inc.'s desire to integrate hordes of desperate help vampires into this community could never succeed, because the vampires' desires are completely orthogonal to the values that this site was founded on and that its community holds dear. Just as SE Inc. has become fixated on those users as its cash cow, so we have become fixated on them as the downfall of the site. And in doing so, both groups have forgotten the users like Scratte - the ones that will benefit us all.

In doing so, we have failed those users by not making information on how to conduct themselves easy to find. It's time for that to end.

**What can we, as the Stack Overflow community, do to better "onboard" new users who really want to help the site, not just themselves?** What can we suggest to Stack Exchange Inc. to achieve the same? Is it as simple as condensing all the years of wisdom of the community into a FAQ-wiki, or are there other procedures that could be implemented to make this actually work?

Related: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390983/70345), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287069/70345)

Comment: "know that Stack Exchange Inc.'s desire to integrate hordes of desperate help vampires into this community could never succeed, because the vampires' desires are completely orthogonal to the values that this site was founded on and that its community holds dear"  -- really?  I can't tell you the number of times a question has been asked without providing enough details, or showing an attempt (as expected and detailed in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), only to have people clamor to answer them.

Comment: Unfortunately, we’ve already seen steps taken in the “let’s hide useful information from low-rep users” direction. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337104/323179. I’d really like to start by seeing that reversed.

Comment: @Taplar That's generally people who don't understand the core values of the site (or have a thing for collecting imaginary internet points, which is a problem far outside our purview).

Comment: When such behavior is allowed to continue for a long period of time, without any noticable ramifications, can it still be considered a core value?

Comment: So he got started in January, posted to anything with a pulse and burned-out after two months.  Swinging wildly to try to hit a valid reason why this happened, didn't land a single punch.  Good thing the meta people are always around to stick a jaw out, maybe the upvotes will keep him inspired.  It's what we do.

Comment: Oh haven't read that answer had tp upvote it, but it rings somehow true. the hole situation is to dispare if you have the tendency to do so. New user don't know the layout and different tags have different rules, so that even old members get it wrong. The user with lots of answers don't get upvoted for what ever reason. and the high rep users answer the same questions over and over again. **Yeahh everybogy is miserable** Oh o forgot moderators, they have to ban people who try to help, becausse the revwers don't understand the differenet rules either and get to decide over a lot of crap

Comment: Well.. this was.. unexpected.

Comment: @Scratte Feel free to post an answer ... you may even get an upvote from Hans!

Comment: That one document idea from Scrattle that captures all the rules things.  I really liked that.

Comment: The "What would help?" part of Scratte's answer mostly summarises thoughts I've had on the subject. Rules should be in the help center, not on Meta. The help center in general is kind of disorganised and hard to navigate. Consider that the Don't Ask, On Topic and Closed Questions pages all address roughly the same thing. The How To Ask page (and the Ask Question page) aren't too useful. I like the idea of sending questions to review prior to making them public, but I'm not sure how scalable it is. There are a bunch of feature requests about all of that around here somewhere.

Comment: I felt sympathetic but confused. My xp starting some 8 years ago was nothing like that and I didn't, haven't, and won't go through all they're going through to try to appease. I still care about the quality of my offerings and SO overall but I'm not going to not ask or answer out of fear. I also disagree with the idea that there's no way to know what's expected. My first question, which isn't great or perfect, was the best I could do based on what I saw and received from help. I had a month of xp in C++ and a few days on SO; it was a positive xp then and has primarily been since.

Comment: As the question eloquently summarizes, this a for-profit company built on the back of a non-profit community, and the goals of both are not aligned. There are only two ways out of this: either the company converts to a non-profit organization and gives the community agency, or the company starts remunerating its content creators just like other content platforms do. Both are unlikely to happen, and anything in between is just band-aids and veneer.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen "...and anything in between is just band-aids and veneer" The content is CC licensed, the company would not need to convert to a non-profit organization, it would be sufficient if a non-profit organization is founded with the goal to continue the original mission and also most users would have to do the switch. On the other hand even that seems unlikely and maybe we just have to live with the imperfection of the structure here. Yes, popular feature requests are completely ignored by the company but then a non-profit organization is not a guarantee for better service either.

Comment: @Trilarion I'd submit that popular feature requests don't get implemented because they don't align with the priorities of the company, or are antithetical to its goals. And while the content is CC-licensed, the platform is definitely not.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen You're right. On the other hand the company pays for the upkeep of the servers, the bandwitth and the maintenance and at least only those who don't know how to setup an adblocker are really affected by the ads. I just meant to say that maybe this is as good as it gets. Band-aids and veneer are all we are going to get realistically.

Comment: @Trilarion "This is as good as it gets" kept companies paying for Experts Exchange subscriptions until Stack Overflow reached maturity. "Realistically, this is all we are going to get" is what kept people buying Microsoft Encarta CDs and Encyclopædia Britannica subscriptions until Jimmy Wales started Wikipedia... Panta rhei, and it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes, change to the better is possible, but it's not guaranteed. Maybe things even get worse. The company could for example start requiring visitors to register or start selling their data or whatnot.

Comment: I'm honoured that this post has been featured. Not because I think it's a good post in and of itself, but because I believe and hope it will help to generate the dialogue, feedback and community interaction in order to build a better community.

Comment: Just a small observation. Looking at the stats (unanswered questions, score of questions or answers) I'd say that SO is rather going downhill in 2020. It isn't working for anyone.

Comment: @Trilarion Interesting! Could you point out where you see those stats? SEDE? Or did I miss some meta post about that?

Comment: I think this question is not going to have a quick solution, but needs to be looked at from the ground up.

1. It’s not clear what the goal of the community is. Is the goal a canonical resource of questions and answers? Or is the goal to help as many people as possible? Or is the goal something else? Those goals are not always necessarily aligned.

2. The incentives of stackoverflow are not clear. What feeds into reputation? If someone optimized for reputation, how would you expect them to behave? If someone is optimizing for altruism, how would you expect them to behave?

Comment: from linked post: "They post their Question and hope/want an answer. Lots of them do not read any help pages. They do not even read the help they get during the process of creating their Question. I really don't think there's anything that can be done about that. Hiding their post will even remove the ability for most other user to comment and help. Just to be clear: There is NO WAY to make people happy while expecting quality, unless they want to provide the quality.". have you read that part, @IanKemp? doesn't sound like "we failing new users".

Comment: @ASh Those are not the new users that want to get engaged :) The ones that do want to get engaged are the "unless they want to provide the quality" ;)

Comment: @Scratte, that is an explanation which is "hidden deep in meta" ;)

Comment: @JanWichelmann "..Could you point out where you see those stats? SEDE? Or did I miss some meta post about that?" Among others a SEDE query like [Historical question grades by week](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1125143/historical-question-grades-by-week) which goes back to Jon Ericson and shows that "good questions" are now less than 50% of all question and steadily declining. I wanted to write a Meta post about this and other signs basically saying that SO is currently failing for everyone, but I won't do it today.

Comment: I tend to ask questions on other sites instead of StackOverflow. Too many times, I have received downvotes or close votes on StackOverflow with no explanation. Once the downvotes hit, it's hard to get any quality answers. I think that many people forget (or don't realize) that it takes real time to compose a question and properly tag it, even if the question is not absolutely perfect. I find that it's often a waste of my time to post here, so I rarely choose to do so. I find other sites to be significantly more friendly, flexible, and respectful.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard People on here usually know that a good question needs a lot of work. If it still gets downvoted, you can come to meta for advice or ask for a reason in comments. Users who voted down usually don't comment (because it is discouraged), but other users might. I often comment possible reasons when I come across a comment asking for advice.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: " it takes real time to compose a question and properly tag it".  Yes, it does.  Is it a barrier to entry?  Absolutely, as well it should be.  A question not worth the trouble to ask properly isn't worth the trouble to answer.  The experience one gains in formulating the question properly is absolutely necessary to become a decent programmer.  When I used to answer questions (before this site when so far down hill), it was actually a joy to read a well formed question - it made me want to invest time in an answer.    Now, not so much.

Comment: One thing I learned - and was reminded of today - is that on SO there really is such a thing as a stupid question and those with 'Answers' seem to clamor over one another to remind you of that.  But you can't police a-holes.  I think if you ask a question on this site you have to accept that someone is likely going to rub your face in it.

Comment: You can't do anything about this because SE Inc wants the exact opposite

Answer (score 107):

I see one big problem with pretty much any possible idea that anybody possibly might come up with: all the "good real estate" where such things could be communicated is owned by the company, which has no interest in fostering quality.

The reason why everything is "hidden away on meta" is that meta is the only place where the community can disseminate such information. We have no access to the tour, the help center, the FAQ, the new question wizard, the question editor sidebar, pop-ups, etc. Those are all owned by the company.

Ten years ago, it was still possible for the community to influence the contents of company-owned help pages in an open and honest constructive dialogue. That bridge, however, seems to have been permanently blown up by the company.

"Hiding stuff away on meta" is actually the *best possible* option available to the community; the only alternative would be to publish it on a third-party site that is under the community's control, but that would be even further away from the main site.

Comment: The problem is that workarounds are for the current active community. The users who already know the frictions and pitfalls. It's not bringing in new members in any workable rate, because the workaround itself needs site experience.

Comment: Another two problems I see are that A) this document would be *huge* if you'd like to discuss all kinds of editorial/close reason edge cases. Sounds like an 80 page manual or so. B) as @Scratte already mentioned in their initial answer, there often is no consensus. Duplicate close-wars in a big tag like JavaScript spring to mind: it gets hammered, then unhammered and answered, only to be rehammered by a third person. So even before writing the document a clear consensus on all kinds of obscure edge cases should be reached.

Comment: @Adriaan A) 80 pages is peanuts compared to the amount of reading I went through on meta :) Even 250 pages is workable, because it's just a "book" and can be a combined tutorial and reference manual for Stack Overflow. As long as it's contained. B) First we'd need to reach consensus on how to determine if a consensus has been reached :D

Comment: I suspect one problem might be that a number of these rules are decided by the community and the company doesn't want to conclusively decide on those rules nor back those rules and opinions too strongly (or maybe they just don't want to spend time collecting and summarising those). Although they do seem to have an interest in "being welcoming", and not making it easy to find the rules does fairly strongly oppose that.

Comment: Last year moderators actually got access to edit a [small snippet of the help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390769/7795130) last year.

Comment: @Adriaan I think leaving obscure edge cases (and discussion of specific cases) to Meta is probably fine, especially if the help center links to relevant subsets of those from various places (or there could be curated FAQs in the help center that are strictly supplementary, i.e. not needed by most people in most cases). But the basics at least need to be covered well in the help center.

Comment: What about a Github repository, where all the relevant decisions and discussions are kept in some kind of SO rules handbook with links to meta discussions in footnotes. It could be edited by everyone and serve as a summary of all the hundreds of meta discussions. Not sure that anyone could build that actually. Maybe Meta just needs a wiki it can edit.

Comment: @Trilarion: You could do the same thing with a community wiki answer on meta. The problem is that such information must be made available during onboarding of new users, that content is owned by Stack Overflow, The Company, and they have no interest in onboarding users who ask good questions, and they have even less interest in onboarding experts that answer questions; they have interest in onboarding as many users as fast as possible to increase their ad revenue and inflate their reported user base.

Comment: @Trilarion I mentioned a review check-list earlier. I did consider making it a styled html page with colour-coding and all the fireworks. And then putting it in a snippet on meta, so one could either just grab it and run it locally or run it directly from the snippet while reviewing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag "You could do the same thing with a community wiki answer on meta." A single answer has a size limit that would probably be too narrow, but a community wiki Q&A with sufficient answers and some sensible ordering of the answers might be doable. What I would fear though is that any Q&A can be locked, deleted, closed for whatever reason at any time. An external repository would have advantages too.

Comment: True, but this makes me expect a site called 'therealstackoverflow' might spring up someday soon. Anyway, crass monetization comes at the end of every economic cycle; this was true in 2002, true in 2010 and it's true now.

Comment: @smci: There are (at least) two such sites already: [Codidact](https://codidact.org/) and [TopAnswers](https://topanswers.xyz/). Both sites were started by former Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange community leaders, and both sites have former Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange community leaders both in their user base and in their developer base. Both were started explicitly to be "Stack Exchange plus Lessons Learned".

Answer (score 73):

I figured that it might help to give another view from a "new" user, who is in a similar (but still a bit different) situation like the one Scratte described; I will focus a bit more on the reviewing/moderation aspect here.

### Asking

Technically, I joined Stack Overflow around three years ago, in order to ask for help on a weird interrupt problem when working on a research kernel. Of course, as an active programmer I have already been reading Stack Overflow answers for years, but I never was really interested into what that weird numbers und bronze/silver/golden dots near the user names meant (I won't ever take part in that anyway, right?). It just looked like a forum with great resources which are not put behind an annoying paywall. That understanding very quickly changed when I posted that first question -- I believe I got the grasp on what is on-topic here quite instantly, just by reading the tour page and one or two pages from the help center.

Since then I am following a few simple rules when asking a question:

1. Is it about programming?
2. Has it been answered before? (i.e., can I find the information by running some Google searches?)
3. Does it have any value for others? (i.e., someone else might have the same problem, no matter how weird it is)
4. Can someone else answer it within a reasonable amount of time, given the corresponding knowledge? Or the other way round: Would *I* bother to answer this question?

So asking on-topic questions never really was a problem for me; this is supported by the fact that none of my questions have been closed yet.

However, I should note that my approach on problem solving naturally leads to very few Stack Overflow questions. Usually I only ask after spending *lots* of time googling and trying myself, so the likelihood of asking a trivial or a duplicate question is quite small.

### Answering & Reviewing

After asking my first question (unanswered, one upvote) and writing some random answer addressing a previously unanswered library compilation problem (no activity there since then), I did not further contribute for more than a year. My "real" activity only started last year in August, when I decided to "return something to the community" after years of passive reading. This is the point where I actively started looking for questions I may be able to answer, and got an understanding of how the reputation and badge system works. Note that I still did not read meta at this point, nor bothered with all that moderation stuff ("Flags?! Is this some kind of [CTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_the_flag) competition?").

That quickly changed with seeing the incoming flood of poor questions; I tried answering some, but got quickly tired. Still, I was collecting reputation and finally got the first moderation privileges (i.e., Triage and First Posts queue). Participating in these queues looked like a good way to a) get rid of bad questions quickly, in order to b) find good questions which I can answer.

This where I *had* to start reading meta -- I really wanted to avoid doing something wrong, so I spent lots of my free time digging through the [faq] posts regarding the Triage queue, flags, closing and so on. I also started lurking in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), in order to get to know some of the most active community members and see some practical moderation.

Thus, the first frustrating experience:

**(I) You have to read *a lot* of unstructured content before being able to do correct moderation**.

After doing some reviews and *reviewing my reviews* (i.e., by looking what other users decided) I noticed that many have obviously *not* read the [faq] posts and randomly clicked on "Requires Editing" or "Looks OK", disputing my "Unsalvagable" flags. This was the second frustrating experience:

**(II) Even though *you* have spent lots of time reading all those instructions, this does not mean that *others* have done that.**

I eventually got tired of Triage and First Posts, due to that and because many of my post flags simply aged away (56 as of now; 159 were marked helpful). This left the impression that I really wasted a lot of time -- especially when these off-topic questions get answered and people earn reputation for it.

### Reading meta

Somewhere around last September I got fully engaged with meta and have been following most discussions there since then. Ironically, the big blow-ups at MSE have shown to me that these sites have a very dedicated community, which I wanted to become a part of, although it was frustrating to see that the company did not plan to improve anything about the various moderation and tooling flaws, and, at the opposite, seemed to be actually *encouraging* asking bad questions.

Last week I finally crossed 2k and started reviewing suggested edits. I really like to do that, since I really feel that I am doing something constructive (my actions directly affect keeping and improving post quality, no aging away). But I also had to spend a lot time reading meta again, in order to work out all those small edge cases -- e.g., code changes in answers: Is it allowed? If yes, how much? What about new library releases? Create a new answer, edit an older one?

This is my third and last frustrating experience as a newcomer:

**(III) There is some meta post with lots of upvotes, but is it really consensus? Is everyone expected follow it?**

Turns out, no: For example, I always [believed that spam flags on gibberish questions are okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345332/lets-get-aligned-on-how-spam-flags-can-be-used). Then I had to read that [a moderator stated that they handle that completely differently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397177/declined-spam-flag-on-gibberish-question#comment768576_397177). I know that there are some areas where a consistent handling is simply impossible, but this one does look like a very clear case to me.

### Conclusion

So, I fear that this has maybe become a bit ranty, but I figured that was needed to point out how "new" users may see the site when trying to learn the ropes. But I also want this post to be constructive, so I asked myself the question, "What would have helped me?".

Having to read before starting moderation is probably hard to avoid, and forcing new reviewers to do so is likely impossible. Maybe one could be quicker and stricter with (short) review bans for folks doing unconstructive reviews? This is a difficult question, and I don't have a practicable drop-in solution for problem (II) at hand.

But for all others who *want* to read and follow the consensus, but do it in a more efficient way, an **organized and (most importantly) *binding* resource** on moderation would be very helpful. How would that work?

- We collect all the spread information from the help center, [faq] and meta in one location.
- This does not need to be a large, consecutive and unreadable document: A well-conceived and searchable structure could divide the content into small parts, which can be found and understood easily.
- If there is a discussion on an edge case and clear consensus (e.g. by reaching a certain ratio between upvotes vs. downvotes), the result is put into that document and thus becomes mandatory for everyone (including moderators). Challenging those is obviously still allowed, by creating an appropriate meta post and meeting the required vote threshold. Note that this is intended for edge cases which are easy to capture (like the gibberish spam flag one) -- there will always be unclear cases, but having clear and easily findable guidelines for the large majority of cases would be certainly helpful.
- Whenever I am unsure whether a question might be on-topic, an answer is NAA, a suggested edit is "too much", and so on, I could just check this resource, and don't have to waste time reading multiple large meta discussions. For example: "Edit adds new language version to answer -> Reject".

This could be done by the community, but official (and technical) support by the company would certainly give it more legitimacy (e.g., by fully replacing the help center). However, it would still be a *huge* amount of work, and we would have to decide on whether it is worth the effort, or if we better keep things as-is and rather focus on small improvements, with the risk of losing or misguiding new members.

Comment: I made a review check-list for myself a long time back. It captured all the cases I ran into while reading posts about reviewing. Perhaps it's a start. But I can't find a place for it anywhere.

Comment: A bit tangential, but decisions based on perceived value to others should have less to do with which questions you're asking and more to do with how you approach asking (and answering) those questions. If you ever have a question, chances are someone else will have it too at some point (if they haven't had it already). I don't think I ever think no-one else will have some question I see, but I often see questions and answers that could've been so much more useful to others with the same question had they been written with that goal in mind.

Comment: @BernhardBarker Yes, this is what I intended to say: Questions should not dump hundred lines of code and ask "What is wrong?", but provide some kind of minimal example (most bugs will probably be discovered at this stage already), and also contain the relevant keywords which are needed to find them. When finding it via a search engine others should only need to briefly scan the question in order to find out whether it matches their problem or not.

Comment: And, when I try to think of who could write such a document in a format that would be clear, readable, and easy to follow, the names which spring to mind are Shog9, Monica Cellio, and Jon Ericson. Oops.

Answer (score 55):

The learning curve for new users (on *all* SE sites) is very steep;
gaining even basic competence requires significant work and effort.

In general that isn't a bad thing, but in this case it is almost entirely artificial and unnecessary.

The sites are difficult to learn because rather than presenting new users with a simple, well defined set of rules, we force them to stumble around for themselves, making what, to those in the know, are blatant errors.
We know that eventually, with enough work, they will get it right.

And then we wonder, *Why don't they understand what we all know?*.
And "*Why do they give up?*"

---

Just look at what a new user sees when they use this site:
[image: top of the home page for SO]

- The only identification is "stack**overflow**".
- The only things one can do are "Search" and "Ask Question".

There is nothing at all to indicate what the site is about, or what kinds of questions can be asked.

Way way down at the bottom is this: "Looking for more? Browse the complete list of questions, or popular tags. Help us answer unanswered questions.".
But again, there is absolutely nothing to indicate what kinds of questions are appropriate.

Yes, people can explore the site; yes, they can discover various help and tour pages; and yes, they can do many things to get a better understanding.
But what is the purpose of making things so difficult if it's not to discourage them?

"*Jump into the deep end and learn to swim!*" is not a good philosophy for these sites.

---

And those users that finally *do* ask a question immediately find rejection, because they are "off-topic" or "opinion based".
These buzzwords have a very specific and well known meaning to advanced users, but to beginners they sound just like ordinary English words with meanings that are quite different from what they are supposed to mean here.

- On the Judaism site I ask about a *Yiddish* version of a *Leonard Cohen* song based on *Hebrew* *scriptures*, and I'm told that it is off-topic.
  Huh?  What could be more related to Judaism than that?
- On other sites I ask "*Why did …?*" and I'm told that the question is opinion-based.
  Huh? I didn't express any opinions, either in the Title or the Body of the question.  What are they talking about?

Yes, I now know that off-topic means that it doesn't match a vague and obscure list of things that are appropriate for the site, and that opinion-based doesn't mean that the question itself is based on opinion, but that the question will solicit opinionated answers.

But how is a new user supposed to know that?

---

> **arcane** adjective
>
> ar·<200b>cane | \ är-ˈkān \
>
> Definition of arcane
> : known or knowable only to a few people : SECRET
> // arcane rites
> // an arcane ritual
>
> broadly : MYSTERIOUS, OBSCURE
> // arcane explanations
> // arcane technical details
>
> — [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arcane)

This single word encompasses the vast majority of problems with this site.

There are two frequent situations where "arcane" is desirable:

- to protect valuable or dangerous knowledge from people that might abuse it.
- to make shallow knowledge *seem* profound, in order to artificially produce an elite group.

But each of these goals actually *goes directly against* what this site is about:

- to provide knowledge to those that *want* it.
- to show that difficult ideas *can* be made easy to understand.

---

The problem isn't specific to SO, but to all SE sites.

If you really want to improve the situation:

- The top of the page should briefly explain what each site is about ("Stack Overflow answers questions about … .").
  This site in particular is especially bad, as the site's name doesn't reflect its purpose in the least.
- The top of the page should give lists of appropriate and inappropriate topics, or at least provide an obvious link to a full, self-contained page that gives this information.
- The top of the page should briefly explain *how* to word a question, or at least have a prominent link to a full, self-contained page that gives this information.
- The top of the page should briefly explain *how* answers will be presented, or at least have a link to a full, self-contained page that give this information.

---

For a set of sites that feels so strongly about questions always being about the appropriate topics and answers always being presented in an objective and verifiable form, I really don't understand why they don't follow their own advice and make their home pages present clear, self-contained, and complete information.

Comment: Technically there's [the new landing page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386505) which new, non-logged on users see, although there's quite a lot of commotion about that as well. Otherwise I agree with you that the amount of information could be better, but preferably then only for "new" users, e.g. gaining the privilege of (optionally?) hiding the enlarged set of rules on top of the page at, say, 1000 rep or so.

Comment: “But the plans were on display…”
“*On display? I eventually had to go down to the cellar to find them.*”
“That’s the display department.”
“*With a flashlight.*”
“Ah, well, the lights had probably gone.”
“*So had the stairs.*”
“But look, you found the notice, didn’t you?”
“*Yes*,” said Arthur, “*yes I did. It was on display in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘Beware of the Leopard'.*”

― Douglas Adams, The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy

Comment: Everything you wrote, plus certain moderators and frequent downvoters who don't want to put in real effort to help people (and choose not to even respond to requests for help).  I've even seen people bragging on SE about all their downvotes.  These are real problems in this little society.

Comment: +1 Having spent years on StackOverflow, I still have absolutely no idea how you find out what is a valid question topic on any of the other SE network sites.

Comment: Don't almost all new users come here from Google to a specific question, though? And as Adriaan pointed out, if a new user does go directly to stackoverflow.com, they'll get a big friendly explanation of how the site works. Your screenshot is of what a user with a few hundred reputation and a gold badge sees when they go to the homepage.

Comment: @MiloP, *I* have a gold badge and a few hundred reputation on many sites, and on many of them I *still* often have trouble knowing what is on-topic and what isn't.

Comment: @RayButterworth It's better than that: I see that many questions are closed before the OP even realises they were meant to do something - because after finding the filing cabinet they missed [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its *penultimate* (for good eyes-are-glazing-over-now effect) section "Post the question and respond to feedback" which gives the vague: **After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments.**

Answer (score 29):

I'm a 'low' reputation user that has been active on the site (including moderation activities) for about a decade. In those early days, I was quite enthusiastic about the idea of getting into the maintenance of this site. Somehow I've managed to keep that self motivation and continue to contribute. Still, some ten years later, I can't fully participate in the moderation of this site.

This is particulary strange to me when I see posts here on Meta from high rep users complaining about poor reviews, typically referring to users who have just gotten to the magical 3000 barrier. When looking at the profiles of those users, they have usually been around for well less than a year, gotten rep through a high traffic tag, and have nearly no actual experience (or guidance) on how to participate in the basic moderation of this site, such as editing posts, voting, flagging, reviewing lower rep queues, etc.... [This has also stood out to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255270/are-we-losing-the-battle-against-the-close-vote-queue/255368#255368) when I've seen the posts about the Close Vote queue.

I can easily see how somebody, who has in a flash got a whole bunch rep, suddenly gets very discouraged when they get hit with their first vote/flag/review ban, with no explanation as to what went wrong. This can even have a harsher effect, on both this site and the user, than on a new poster who gets their question downvoted and deleted without explanation. With a new low-rep user, there are still open questions and potential (both good and bad). At least with a lots-of-rep-in-short-period user, you know you're probably getting somebody who can verifiably contribute to the site *in some way*.

The fact is, the site doesn't do a very good job of:

- Easing users into the maintenance of this site.
- Encouraging/expediting those users into those responsibilities who clearly want to be a part of that and obviously have a knack for it from the beginning.

I'm sure we've chased away a lot of good users either because of that first harsh response, or their frustration at being able to do so little with the skills and interest they have.

That's my answer to this question. I do have ideas and, if there is interest, I'm happy augment this post with a few vague suggestions. I haven't done it in this post as I know that this is a contentious topic and have suffered the negative meta effect wrath by very innocently encroaching onto the subject from a [purely grammatical point of view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308498/established-user-privilege-has-an-inaccurate-description).

Comment: This is the root of all problems - new users will feel overwhelmed when faced many negative response without any cause, but the SO rules applaud it.

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps I'm atypical.  I have medium reputation (3k+), but I don't really care about my reputation (very much).  I cared a bit until I got to about 2k (I figured that once I had 2k, I had enough rep to be taken seriously).  Now it's a just a *nice to have*.

I've never asked a question.  The three times that I sat down to compose a question, I tried to do it the right way.  I created an minimal repro. I went through everything I'd tried, re-searched the web for answers (to include as references).  Each time I eventually answered my own question.  I considered each of those half days I spent creating a question I never asked a good use of my time.

My very first answer on SO got a nearly immediate comment that starts *"That's useless..."*.  Though it did end up with 4 up-votes and two down-votes, the accepted answer was much better and I learned something in the process -- and learning something is the goal.

Maybe it's because I've been around the block a few times (my first dev job started in July, 1982) and maybe it's because I worked a dozen years in high-end dev support for a major company, but I've never dug deep in the site for how to ask, how to create a minimal repro, how to answer or what's acceptable.  I just read existing questions and answers and picked up how the site works.  If I commented or answered something and I didn't do it quite right, someone would tell me and I'd adjust from there.  I can assure you I've never dug deep on *Meta* (I think I've looked for one thing here in the last several years).  This might be my second post.

I'm sorry, but I find the SO site very self-explanatory.

Comment: Have you reviewed a lot?

Comment: Nope, only a bit

Comment: There's a difference to being able to post something good and determine where the line between OK / Should be Closed for whatever reason / Should be removed ASAP on other users posts. For that, there are a lot of rules. Maybe you're just fortunate to have the ability to determine that without going down the meta path :) I didn't. I find the most tricky ones to be how-to Questions, and I'm not likely to risk asking any of those.

Comment: "...I find the SO site very self-explanatory." Me too. Asking, answering and voting is quite straightforward. But there are nuances and often people get downvotes piled on without really knowing why. On the other hand, many new questions from new users are ill posed and not answerable without considerable edits or are badly researched and most likely duplicates. You somehow seem to have avoided these pitfalls, but others do not. Not sure though if more reading material would help them really. I put my money on that one day we can teach an AI how to teach programming and let it do the job here.

Comment: While I agree and believe that, generally, Stack Overflow isn't too hard to figure out, I think we can do better anyway. The fact is, we apply rules very inconsistently, and this means that some people will get very inconsistent feedback and be confused. This won't be true for everyone, but it's true for enough individuals that it's probably worth improving.

Comment: " ...but I don't really care about my reputation (very much)..." You may not. But this site very clearly does, atleast by the way its structured. Being at 3k opens up a batch of moderating possibilities. Fine. But then there are perfectly valid posts complaining about the exceptionally poor reviewing, often by 'low rep' users who've just acquired that level, and who've previously never really taken part in any actual moderation (and often leading to quick bans). This is a problem for both the site and for retaining those users. And it has some straightfoward fixes.

Comment: _" Each time I eventually answered my own question."_ Sounds like a good candidate for a self-answered question to save someone else half a day. ;-)

Comment: @Michael My only question was self-answered. I figured if it took me three hours to research it someone else probably spent at least as much time so I might as well answer it. It lead to official documentation getting updated when someone filed a bug report. Self-answered questions don't get the love they should.

Answer (score 21):

As I see it, the root cause here is a lack of leadership. The site has become a lot of things for a lot of people whose purpose is often at odds with each other. And that despite the origin of Stack Overflow as being very focused on a particular goal.

It started with a sort-of-[BDFL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life)</sup> who was very visible and vocal and set the tone. Over time he faded away and *power* was dispersed among the *community*. The problem is twofold:

### 1. "Power"

BDFL Atwood had great *influential* power and was largely able to set the tone of what Stack Overflow was supposed to be. When he stepped back, that void was slowly filled by a group of people all voicing their opinions. While the community has always been very vocal from the beginning, the BDFL largely had "the last word." Now that nobody has the last word, there's very little consensus what the site is supposed to be exactly.

SE Inc. ultimately has the last word, but they've mostly taken a step back. They're not setting the tone nor showing a direction. At best they're "supporting" the community or fulfil requests for feature implementations. For better or worse, they're letting the community regulate itself.

Of course there's another kind of "power": moderation power. *Everyone* on Stack Overflow is a moderator (once you've cleared an initial reputation hurdle). There's nobody with the last word in terms of this kind of power. Oh yes, there are *Moderators ♦* alright, but they have little to do with question moderation. Moderators ♦ largely don't decide what posts are okay and which aren't, that power is dispersed among the community at large.

In fact, the two kinds of power can be entirely orthogonal: those exerting the power of moderation have a very tangible effect on the everyday tone of the site, while most of them do not participate on Meta at all. Those that wield influential power by being vocal on Meta don't necessarily exert their moderation powers much at all.

### 2. "Community"

Which smoothly brings me to the problem of "community": there's way more than one "community" on Stack Overflow. You can slice this many ways, on the asker-answerer axis, the newbie-pro axis, the various subgroups belonging to different tags, the quality-vs-helpful crowds…

Each group has different priorities and goals and most of them are **at odds with each other**. And **none of them has the last word** and **none of them has the ultimate power**.

It's really a perfect storm:

- largely equally powerful groups
- ...which are often at odds with each other
- ...with no tie breaker
- ...and most of the power that can be wielded being **negative** (close votes)

It's no wonder new users feel like they're caught in a turf war. And the rules of the war are written sprawled across Meta, and each "side" selectively links to the bits and pieces they believe are relevant, and by now you can find posts supporting virtually any viewpoint you like on Meta.

---

Do I have a solution for this mess? Nope… ‍♂️ Nothing easy. You need someone who understands these power dynamics, who has a vision for a better structure, who can implement changes, who can identify the correct changes to make, and who is willing to do so.

Comment: So SE needs to hire 5 Community Managers to fulfill each of the capabilities mentioned in that last sentence. Surely no sane head exists that combines those skills in one person ....

Comment: Thank you. I can stop my quest to find a real live rainbow coloured unicorn now :)

Comment: @rene Find the spell that brings Steve Jobs back from the dead. Or Jesus or somebody like it…

Comment: Shog was the closest for a long time. He certainly took on part of the influence as jeff stepped back.

Answer (score 19):

As a new user, I think the core concepts of why Stack Overflow exists is commonly confused.

---

> "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for **professional** and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a **library** of detailed answers to **every question** about programming."

• Define **Library**

In other words, Stack Overflow is a programmers **encyclopedia**. Any topic or question you may ask, a verified professional has already written their professional take on it.

• Define **Every Question**

<sup>(Every question does not include: Vague questions, personal questions, and duplicate questions)</sup>

It's not a Q&A website in the sense you can ask whatever personalized question you want and get someone to help you out (although this could be interesting on a separate site). The questions you ask be should questions that are likely to be asked by someone else.

> Bad Question:
>
> **Why doesn't this work?**
>
> Reason: Even though this is a commonly asked question, it's extremely vague.

> Bad Question:
>
> **How do I get my two dogs and cats line up to foo and bar jsnwddnsnrfwefge. It's for my game.**
>
> Reason: No one's going to ask this question in the future, and it's solely for yourself.

You're questions can't be too vague, but they also shouldn't be too specific to yourself. You must first understand the core concepts of your question before you ask it, so that others can learn from it. I also suspect that 'Bounties' may be misused.

> Good Question:
>
> **What is the difference between a** ***reference type*** **and a** ***value type?***
>
> Reason: People can glean good information from this.
>
> Maybe a professional is specifically an expert in this question, so that *everyone* can learn from them.

Your question doesn't have to be extravagant. The simpler and to the point it is, the better.
The answer is encouraged be professional and extravagant.

---

**It must be practical. 

It must be able to provide a learning opportunity for someone else. 

Your question should be one that would be a shame if it wasn't asked.**

---

New users might not get this right away. I definitely didn't. If their questions could be filtered to a different programming Stack Exchange site, that would be brilliant. Because their questions are important as well.

Everyone has different opinions on what a useful practical question is. A question might not be practical for everyone, but it might be very practical for a select few. Example: If every *[regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)* question was taken down, it would be a sad day for some of us.

If a question could go through some sort of review phase, similar to how edits already do that would be wonderful. And if some sort of feedback could be given back to every question, that would be supreme.

Comment: I especially like the last paragraph. Recruitment of volunteers for that isn't easy, but that is what we have gamification for (though difficult to get right. It must be possible to use a dynamic / adaptive approach rather than fixed rules set in advance (like the current system)).

Comment: I'm not sure that I 100% agree here.  It feels like you are judging a good question by its Title or generalised single-sentence summary of the question.  A good question can be extremely isolated and the snowflake question may likely never again be asked or searched for.  However, "knowing&caring volunteers" will be able to boil down what is asked and edit the title to be something likely to be searched for and include relevant keywords and tags to aid in SEO.  I never liked the now-removed "Too Localized" close reason.

Comment: @mickmackusa A 'help desk' type SE site could be extremely useful. Any kind of programming question can be asked there. The 'encyclopedia' site is one strictly for professional usage, with descriptive and research-filled questions, and professional answers. I think this could make it much easier on volunteers trying to filter everything on this one site. I think this could idea go up for more discussion.

Comment: I don't know if I would support a separate "purgatory" for content.  I fear this might be a bottleneck for entry into "qualified long storage" (heaven). If I was a researcher, then I would need to scour content in two places.  I don't think I mind the current SE structure -- granted it's not perfect because too many users don't [know how / care to] up/down/close vote properly to help distinguish between content that should be in "heaven"/"hell".

Comment: @mickmackusa You bring up a good point. Good questions vs. Bad questions seems unreasonable to me. Maybe an 'encyclopedia' type site could be a blog where people make inputs on what they deem important and beneficial. Granted there's already Wikipedia for that, but maybe a programming-centered one would be good (With gamification and all).

Answer (score 12):

**Offer guidance and encouragement to newcomers rather than silent downvotes, meaningless criticism, and closures.**

As a very new user, I would say that simply explaining to very new users why their question has been closed or could be improved in an understandable and helpful way would be immensely helpful, rather than users simply 'silently' downvoting and closing with no explanation. I'm not saying that this should be done for every closed question - but could be considered for those who are obviously newcomers and are in the dark.

For context, I have been using Physics and Mathematics SE for many years, although haven't started asking and answering questions until recently. The community on Physics and Maths SE is kind, encouraging, and helpful - even to newcomers who ask questions which probably should be closed. Certainly there are rules but they aren't kept so strictly - users are more interested in answering a question even if it is a little vague or off-topic, rather than simply closing and downvoting it. In contrast, I have found the community here to be much more harsh, scathing, and hostile - especially to newcomers. Certainly from my perspective, it seems that users are more interested in downvoting a bad question than answering a good one.

When I posted my first question on here, it was closed as 'lacking focus' and received a few downvotes. I had no idea why the question lacked focus, it was asking about a fairly specific problem. From my point of view, it wasn't significantly different from other questions I had seen answered on here, and I had searched the website extensively for a similar question, to no avail.

I then went onto meta to ask why my question had been closed as 'lacking focus' and asked how it could be more focussed. This, I thought, was the whole point of meta. This question received even more downvotes than the original and just received a host of comments to the tune of 'well obviously, this lacks focus, I'm not sure how it could be less focussed!' Responding in this way is simply rude and unhelpful - something which would *never* be experienced on Mathematics and Physics SE. I'm not sure that there could be anything more off-putting for a newcomer.

In the end I deleted both questions and don't really bother asking or answering questions on here, and if I do (like now) I just expect it to be downvoted and don't really care that much. Stack Overflow, from my perspective, is an unnecessarily toxic place for newcomers, and asking a question is really a last resort for me.

Comment: I am sorry you had a bad experience here on meta. Personally, I consider a question of how to improve an existing question *very* important. I'd rather have that than clueless users post one after the other "too broad", "off topic", and indeed "not focused" (I am not in favor of that term!) only to be banned shortly afterwards. I am glad to see your current visible questions seem to have had a fairly positive reception. But honestly, "asking a question is really a last resort for me" *should be* your primary objective. Most questions *have* been asked.

Comment: @Owen I support your suggestion of 'offering guidance', but 'encouragement' should be reserved for positive actions (very good questions/answers). Generally, I am also against silent downvotes, but due to the volume of the content that curators go through offering personalized advice in the comments does not seem to be always practical. Overall, I believe (not supported by the data), MSE and PSE do not suffer from a 'high volume of low-quality content' as much as Stack Overflow. The traffic on these websites is also far lower (~150,000 acceptable questions on PSE vs 20,000,000 on SO).

Comment: It is also interesting to note that there are two websites on the SE network for mathematics: MSE and MO. MO probably has the highest quality standards than any other website on the SE network. There also exists Physics Overflow (outside of the SE network) with a similar mission as MO. This is, most likely, why MSE and PSE are more welcoming to newcomers. I wonder if a similar model could work for Stack Overflow. Surely, it should not be too difficult to merely set up another website for 'professional programmers'.

Comment: On the mark, I see many questions especially from new users, that are downvoted with no reason given, or closed with a vague predefined reason (opinion based etc). How is the user supposed to know what to do next time (if there is one)?

Comment: Agreed - many users on Stack Overflow only [skim](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2018/aug/25/skim-reading-new-normal-maryanne-wolf) questions for keywords (don't actually read) to match previous questions. But Mathematics SE is a special case as it is a homework site that even happily accepts questions ***without any demonstrated effort*** (straight homework dumps - effectively work orders). Accepts = answers, no comments, zero close votes and no downvotes.

Comment: ironically I used to comment on my downvotes until the welcome wagon thing made it so curators (like myself) were so attacked for their comments and efforts that it was just better to erred on not saying anything than watching comments get repeatedly deleted. The sad fact is SO just punishes everyone involved experienced users & new users alike.

Comment: You should link the deleted questions. High reputation users can see them. I am not a fan of claims that someone was unfairly treated without evidence. There is *very* often more to the story. "I just expect it to be downvoted and don't really care that much. Stack Overflow, from my perspective, is an unnecessarily toxic place for newcomers, and asking a question is really a last resort for me." And this is you jumping to conclusions because you faced some unpleasant feedback. You're the only one who can step back and self reflect on what you could have done better rather than deem SO evil.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think the whole point is that as a newcomer, one doesn't necessarily know what 'could have been done better', which is why I am suggesting giving feedback.

Comment: That doesn't imply downvoting is rude, which is what you assert in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Background

I tried to answer this question soon after it was posted. However, following a thoughtful discussion in the comments (courtesy of [fbueckert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1197934/fbueckert) and [Adriaan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5211833/adriaan)) my answer received a number of downvotes. During my first attempt to address the question, I interpreted the question too literally, ignoring the negative impact that my suggestion could have on those who volunteer to curate the content. The summary of my first proposed solution was to encourage the moderators/curators of the website to provide elaborate comments that argument their decisions to downvote/flag/close/delete a question in an attempt to educate new users (edit: oddly enough, I believe that my proposal was essentially identical to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398173/9716869), which was well-received). While I believe that it is a good answer to the question

> What can we, as the Stack Overflow community, do to better "onboard"
> new users who really want to help the site, not just themselves?

taken at its face value, overall it is not a very good solution, as it puts even more strain on those who volunteer to curate the content.

---

## A radical solution?

Firstly, let me present my own analysis of the problem as I understand it now:

- Hordes of new users post a massive volume of low-quality content on the website, often ignoring its official rules and regulations.
- Furthermore, ignoring those who ignore the official rules and regulations, there exists a meta-culture that is not immediately apparent to the new users. Thus, there exist many borderline cases: a new user thinks that they follow the official rules and regulations and yet they receive largely negative feedback on their actions, deferring them from improvement and further participation.
- Curators are overwhelmed with the traffic of low-quality content. Due to its sheer volume, it is difficult to provide constructive and elaborate feedback on the negative actions of certain individuals who marginally fail to meet the implicit and understated standards of the website (predominantly determined by the meta-community), yet are genuinely trying to improve and become accepted into the SO community.

I believe that the biggest problem is still the 'large volume of very low-quality content' faced by the volunteer curators. Once this problem is resolved and the volume of the low-quality content is reduced, it will take the pressure off from the curators and they will have more time to deal with more borderline cases and help those who want to be helped and can be helped.

The implementation of my proposal would inevitably require actions and support both from the company and the meta-community. However, if done in the right manner, I believe that it will fully resolve nearly all of the problems mentioned above simultaneously.

### Trials for everyone

While the registration on the website should remain free for everyone, certain actions should only be allowed to be performed after a user demonstrated competence in programming and understanding of the rules and regulations of the website.

1. Anyone who wishes to post a question, first needs to demonstrate the ability to code and think algorithmically, as well as knowledge and understanding of the official rules/regulations/policies. The trial would consist of two parts. The first part may come in the form of writing a very simple program in a language of one's choice (do we really need anyone posting questions on this website before they can write a bubble sort in any programming language?*). The trials should be based around the problems whose solutions are already available on the website. The second part would come in the form of a multiple-choice questionnaire about the rules and regulations of the website. This test would ensure that all question-askers possess the minimum level of competency and have a serious attitude towards the website.
2. Anyone who wishes to answer a question would need to undergo a similar trial, but it should be tougher. Perhaps, they should also be assessed upon their competency in the use of the English language.

*The difficulty of the technical questions for the trials, of course, should be a subject for an explicit open discussion (courtesy of [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b)).

Of course, such trials would need to be fully automated and the pool of questions would need to be updated regularly (courtesy of [Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte))

Also, of course, existing users with high reputation should be exempt from such trials. While this solution may seem slightly radical, I believe that it is the only solution that will have an immediate and strictly positive impact on all aspects of the problems faced by those who want to improve the website and the community:

- The volume of low quality content will be significantly reduced.
- Noone wishing to advertise/spam on the website will ever bother to pass the trial.
- Noone incapable of conversing in the English language will be able to pass the trial.
- Noone incapable of producing even the simplest program will be able to pass the trial.
- Every person who posts a question/answer will have (at least once) read the rules and the regulations of the website.
- The users will think twice before registering multiple accounts in an attempt to 'return with vengeance'.
- Finally, the pressure from the curators of the content will be lifted and they will have significantly more time and energy to be patient with those who truly wish to learn and help to make this website better.

---

## Side Remarks

- Having written this answer, I started thinking about something slightly unrelated. Can Stack Overflow become/be thought of/seen as/presented as a, kind of, predominantly self-governing and self-regulated free private educational establishment? I guess, this is too much of a deviation from the current direction, but there may be some profit derived from this pattern of thinking too. Naturally, 'selling' Stack Overflow (or dedicated non-existing parts of it) this way would have a dramatic positive impact on the quality of the content.
- It is interesting to note that similar proposals were presented on the meta in the past (although my own proposal is different in its approach from the previous proposals) and received a high degree of support from the community: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367092/changing-new-users-expectations-of-this-site-before-they-ask-their-question-b), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252804/asking-questions-privilege-should-be-severely-limited-for-new-users) and [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly).

Comment: It's a somewhat radical idea :) I think it would be too time consuming to check that someone implemented bubblesort as opposed to quicksort, though. Perhaps just a program that can be tested against output from a input. Surely it would have to be changed very often as else users would just share their admission code. Or entire Stack Overflow entry cheat-sheets.

Comment: I like the idea of solving problems that have already been solved on the site. Basically, ask the potential questioner to find a dupe :). If they can do that, and restate the answer without plagiarizing, they get to ask a new question.

Comment: @Scratte The implementation details would need to be thought through very carefully. I have merely presented an idea that will, inevitably, need to be refined. Certainly, the entire testing process would need to be fully automated. However, the pool of questions would need to be updated regularly (e.g. twice a year or so). The cheat sheets is not a severe problem. The idea is not to make everyone memorize the all the rules and regulations, but make them aware of their existence and demonstrate some level of dedication and patience.

Comment: @Scratte In any case, thank you for your suggestion. I have added it to the answer in the form of a clarification.

Comment: What is a bubblesort? ; - )

Comment: @KevinB Google is your fiend? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644858/bubblesort-implementation + https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58178/bubble-sorting-an-int-array

Comment: @KevinB In any case, this is just an example, it may be decided later to start with much simpler questions (e.g. factorial or Fibonacci numbers)?

Comment: My username seem to appear in the most unexpected places :) Nice touch with finding bubblesort implementations, though I suspect KevinB was joking (perhaps even implying that high-rep users may not all be able to pass the test) ;)

Comment: @Scratte I am sure it was meant to be a sarcastic remark. However, I believe that it addressed the valid point that the difficulty of the questions for the trials would need to be decided collaboratively.

Comment: eh, well, my point was two fold: 1, many users (such as myself) who haven't had a formal programming-related education wouldn't know algorithms/methods by name, and 2, that wouldn't necessarily make the test not useful, as being able to research and figure out what, for example, bubblesort is and how to implement it would be just as good as knowing it before hand and being able to do it immediately for such a test. That's all we really want to know, is the user able to do their own research and solve their own problems.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you for the clarification. Indeed, I believe that the questions should be difficult enough to require some effort (and ability to use Google or Stack Overflow search) from the beginners, yet easy enough to be completed in much less than 30 minutes by any even remotely competent programmer.

Comment: This would be a suggestion I would highly support; raising the barrier to entry ensures we can maintain our repository.  Unfortunately, doing so would undoubtedly make SO even more hated for being so unwelcoming.  Nothing says gatekeeping like, "Hey, welcome here!  Complete this test for entry." Nor do I doubt the company would agree; SO is for, "everyone who codes", and isn't willing to to publicly state that there actually *is* a barrier to entry that users have to meet.  It doesn't jive with wanting to be welcoming, y'know?  Love the idea, doubt it'll ever happen.

Comment: @fbueckert Firstly, in my view, "everyone who codes" is not equivalent to "everyone who wants to start coding" or "everyone who has never coded before" (of course, for question-askers the 'trial' can be very simple). Secondly, anyone will be able to use the website after the introduction of the 'trials'. There are already many privileges that can only be earned by meeting certain achievements (this requires some level of support from the community via upvotes). My answer is merely stating that 'asking questions' should be migrated to the category of privileges that one has to earn.

Comment: @fbueckert Also, I believe that receiving a message similar to 'Sorry, you did not pass the test. Please come back and try again.' is less 'unwelcoming' than comments akin to 'When will you finally learn how to read? The rules are right here --->' from annoyed and overworked curators :).

Comment: Like I said, I absolutely agree.  I discussed it with @Catija [last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381430/spurned-authors-deleting-their-questions-after-they-are-closed-as-duplicate#comment679268_381430), where SE couldn't even clarify what it meant.  I'm rather cynical that SE would ever be willing to close the floodgates.

Comment: I have to agree with fbueckert, the barrier for entry would be too great / unattractive for the company to tolerate.  Relate to how I currently engage with SE sites, when I first started contributing on SO I was "all legs and no brains". I was feverishly straying answers over a high volume of pages that should have been closed.  It was YEARS later before the right sequence of comments came from passionate curators and I saw "the light". Now I feel that it is long overdue for this community to step up member grooming. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397526/2943403 this helps curators to groom.

Answer (score 7):

The question misses the forest for the trees. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398198), posted by [deceze ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze), comes the closest to what I want to see expressed here. There is a more fundamental issue here than just communication to new users.

First, a brief description of my own experience. The vast majority of my contribution to Stack Exchange is on Stack Overflow. Even there, it's been a mixed bag. I find that as long as I focus on answering questions, things go okay, but once moderation activities come into the picture, there's a lot of friction. Some of this is just the basic issue of people not liking being told "you're doing it wrong", whether correctly or not, but a lot of it is due to the factors that deceze mentions in their answer. More on this below.

I think my recent experiences with the [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) site illustrate this well. I have approached that site with the exact same philosophy and intent as I do here. My contributions have been minimal, but so far they have largely not just been ignored, but *rejected* by the "community". I've proposed edits to answers in an attempt to improve them by adding crucial information (specifically called out in the Help center as a good reason to edit a post) only to see those edits not only rejected, but by reviewers (not the author of the post) using the justification of *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit"*, something that is patently incorrect for these edits. Yet, this happened three different times (the first example, I could see giving the reviewers the benefit of the doubt, but the other two there is simply no question that the reason they gave for rejecting didn't apply).

More recently, I posted a self-answered question to address the fact that the question I had was not already answered on the site (I found the answer by combining information on pages I found elsewhere on the Internet), only to see a couple of users start posting comments under the question that did not in any way address the question, even as they insisted that it did. These users felt it important to spend their time trying to convince me that my question was asking something other than what it was.

I have a couple of basic rules I follow on Stack Overflow:

1. The author of the question does *not* get a say as to whether the question is clear and answerable. That is only for the community to decide, and for each individual of the community to decide for themselves.
2. Conversely, *only* the author of the question gets to say what the question is actually asking. Others can try to infer meaning, ask for clarifications, etc., but only the person who wrote the question has any claim to authoritatively stating what the question means.

Yet I found myself confronted by people insisting that they, not I, knew what I was asking.

I cannot ever know what the true motivations of someone else's actions are, but I have a hard time interpreting the actions of these individuals as having constructive, helpful intent. Rather, they seemed to be wanting to play some sort of power game with me.

And these experiences are not unique to Superuser. I have had similar experiences on other non-Stack Overflow sites.

**So how does this relate to the question here?** It's for the issues mentioned by deceze in their answer: this site (and other Stack Exchange) sites ultimately wind up being the battleground on which two or more disparate communities fight with each other. Some of these people have good intentions, and of those some are able to express those intentions productively while others struggle with that. But many of the people don't have good intentions at all. They are here to stroke their own egos, something that is enabled and exacerbated by the reputation-point model of the sites.

**What can be done?**

I think that it starts with two major structural changes that must be made:

1. First and foremost, the Stack Exchange company needs to decide what it is they want the site to be.
   There are honest disagreements about whether the site should be open to any and all questions a person might ask, vs. imposing strict standards on questions. These disagreements don't often come up explicitly, but you see it all the time when really crappy questions get upvoted (presumably by the people who feel it's more important to encourage new users than worry about the quality of a question) as well as down-/close-voted. These are users acting honestly, but under competing goals. The lack of company-imposed guidance regarding what actually is acceptable perpetuates this situation.
2. Once the company has decided what the site is supposed to be, it needs to take a firm hold of the reins, imposing strictly enforced standards to ensure the site is what it's supposed to be.
   It's well and good to solicit the aid of community members to help with the moderation duties. But those duties *cannot* be left solely to the community. The current philosophy is "the community will decide", but this philosophy assumes that there is just one community when in fact you have multiple people involved in moderation all of whom have disparate goals, often widely conflicting.
   The community-run model has of course the advantage of being very low cost. The burden of ensuring the quality of the site is carried mostly by volunteers, which is a great way to ensure a nice profit margin. But it results in the site having no reliably-consistent rules for quality, which not only leads to less quality, but also often-intense conflict between people who have differing opinions as to what level of quality is even appropriate. This conflict solves nothing and makes the site that much more unpleasant to participate in.

These two things are radically different from how the Stack Exchange network is managed now. I don't know whether the company will have the stomach to take a stronger stance in this respect. But IMHO it's the only way to really improve things. The issues at hand are much more fundamental than new users just not having access to information. They are seated in problems such as the fact that many new users don't give a crap *at all* about the quality of the site, as long as someone will do their work for them, and many established users either don't give a crap *at all* about the quality of the site, as long as they get to lord it over other users, or they have a very different idea of what "quality" means in the context of a site like this.

With these structural changes, it becomes feasible for the company itself to provide meaningful recourse to users who feel wronged. Two big problems exist today in that respect:

1. There's this attitude that bad behavior just isn't worth pursuing unless it has some major impact. Did someone manage to sneak a few serial downvotes past the detection script? So what? It's just fake Internet points.
   Well, that's actually true of course. But it misses the bigger picture: it does violate the standard of behavior in a clear way, and it *could* be addressed by applying enough manpower. And frankly, I think the site could impose an automatic rule prohibiting any user from voting on any post from another user after their own post has been voted on by that user. This would eliminate the revenge-voting that makes the site so unpleasant to engage with at times, without having any material effect on the overall quality of the site (if a post really needs a downvote, some other user in the community will eventually provide it…we already block some votes that could be made, simply by restricting the number of votes a user has each day, so it's not like very vote is precious).
2. But more problematic is that there isn't even a clear standard as to what constitutes "wronged". The company has left to the community the decisions as to what is actually useful conduct on the site, which conveniently (for the company) means that there's not even any meaningful way that the company *could* adjudicate conflicts with respect to moderation.
   Frankly, this is very reminiscent of the "safe harbor" protections web sites enjoy. It seems like a great idea for a web site to let their users post anything and everything. After all, they are just the "provider" of the platform, not in charge of editing decisions. But, look where that got us on social media. And indeed, companies like Facebook and Twitter are having to rethink that approach, because the hands-off approach leaves those platforms open for the worst of actors.
   Stack Exchange hasn't gotten to that point, partly of course because it's just a fundamentally different way to share information than social media. But I think the lessons still apply, and I think that if the company is serious about fostering a positive experience for all involved, they will need to take a much more hands-on approach toward governance of the content of the site.

These problems aren't solveable simply through improved communication. Without a clear vision of what Stack Exchange actually wants their site to be, you're never going to see the site become *anything* other than fodder for the lowest common denominator.

Comment: For posted questions: You can try preempt it by adding comments to the question right after it is posted with the meta information that will answer their questions (presumes you know what the other users' likely comments are going to be). It is also important to ***occupy the position of the first comment*** as it sets the tone for the rest of the comments.

Comment: Maybe you are right-what exactly does Stack Overflow want to be? Be a noobs friendly babysitter website, or a Self-entertainment party of elites?

Comment: @Flithor: I think it's probably possible for the Stack Exchange company to figure out exactly what type of site they want without resorting to over-simplified, inflammatory language. In any case, there's no reason to think that SE couldn't be newbie-friendly without falling into the trap of babysitting, and likewise can insist on professional behavior without being snobbish.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I know it, But this is my anger after having suffered Downvote bullying in SO, I also hope SO can get better, but before it, I won't be happy with SO's current community atmosphere. - From a user whose many questions that was inexplicably downvote to unable to ask.

Comment: If the SO no longer encourages any "no reason" downvote, it can at least make the community atmosphere 200% friendly - let the newcomers know what they have done wrong, rather than let them confused.

Comment: @Flithor: frankly, one of the best things SE can do to improve things for newcomers is to be more strict about quality. For example, defaulting every post from a new person as "closed" and requiring them to go through a review queue where the post can be opened for public viewing. This seems hostile to newcomers, but reducing the flood of utter crap that users normally have to do with would likely help the experienced members of the community treat in a more gentle and welcoming way the few new users who are in fact acting in good faith (including, presumably, yourself).

Comment: I have only one appeal - reduced "no reason" downvote in community - because it won't "improve" anything.

Comment: Link the specific posts and edits you discuss. We should be able to examine these situations for ourselves to determine if we think your view is biased.

Comment: @jpmc26: I appreciate your concern. However, I provided that part of my answer for context only; it doesn't matter whether you think I'm biased about it or not, as the rest of the answer doesn't rely on the specifics of those situations. And I feel it would be inappropriately self-serving of me to draw attention to those specific issues. If you really care and think it's important, the SE sites don't hide that type of activity from others examining a user's profile, so you can find them easily enough. (note that comments have been deleted, so you'll still be missing some of the specifics)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Specifics always influence the conclusions you draw from a situation. I suggest the opposite: it is far more self serving to make it difficult for others to examine your evidence for themselves.

Comment: Specifically, I would dispute this criticism: "Yet I found myself confronted by people insisting that they, not I, knew what I was asking." It is very often the case that someone with experience and knowledge has a better understanding of a problem than the person asking about it. As such, they can see where the asker is missing knowledge, is confused, or is straight up wrong. They can see several steps *beyond* the asker's current question and can identify pitfalls and problems that will come later. This allows them to recommend something the asker *doesn't want* but probably needs.

Comment: It also means they're better suited to recognize commonalities with other problems that may not be immediately obvious to the asker. All of these things would make it reasonable to point the asker to something they would not immediately accept, and indeed, users commonly complain that their questions aren't duplicates despite the best answer being readily available in the target. Whether this is what you faced or the people you spoke with actually did not understand cannot be distinguished without examining the specifics.

Comment: @jpmc26: again, I appreciate your concern, but frankly...you have no idea what you're talking about in this particular situation. _"It is very often the case that someone with experience and knowledge has a better understanding of a problem than the person asking about it"_ -- it's true that sometimes occurs. However, I'm an expert myself and knew exactly what I was asking in my self-answered question. In any case, if _that_ is the thing you are particularly interested in, then you're out of luck: those comments have all been deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "...but frankly...you have no idea what you're talking about in this particular situation." What a crock. I specifically asked for the evidence, which explicitly leaves open the possibility that you were correct. Asking for that evidence in no way, shape, or form means I don't know what I'm talking about, and that goes doubly when you agree with my point a sentence a later. This kind of argumentative BS is exactly why being able to examine the evidence for oneself is so important.

Comment: @jpmc26: _"What a crock"_ -- really? Tell me, in this particular situation, what specific knowledge is it that you think you have? Because it seems to me that if you had any clue about the specific situation, you wouldn't be wasting your time hypothesizing about things that simply don't apply.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It isn't about what knowledge I do or don't possess. It's about *you* leaving out a lot of information. "hypothesizing about things that simply don't apply" How the heck am I supposed to figure out whether they apply when you provide no info by which I can make that determination?

Comment: @jpmc26: _"How the heck am I supposed to figure out whether they apply when you provide no info by which I can make that determination?"_ -- you can either trust me or not. Believe it or not, people do take other's word at face value on a regular basis, especially in low-stakes scenarios such as this. In any case, as you have already stated that the information you want is information that no longer exists, there is nothing I can do that would satisfy you. The statements in question were posted as comments and have since been removed. Talk to a moderator if you think it's that important.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I've experienced a lot of pushback answering questions. I dared to mention a tool that might help and barely could keep my account because it was considered illegal advertisement. I'm not sure if you might want to dial back a bit on the strictness of things.

Having said that, I'm very happy that Stack Overflow exists! Thank you.

I think it might help if you don't assume the worst about your users. Maybe they tried to comply with your rules but failed, no need to fret about it.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, you can't.

I'm a new user. This question comes up in the sidebar and for some reason I've dedicated close to four hours of my Saturday morning to learning about all the drama that has led here. I finally know why everyone has "reinstate Monica" in their names, I learned about the CC licensing thing, I read resignation letters and news articles and suggestions and did everything Scratte talked about. So I think it's fair to say I've made an effort to do the homework and make sure that this is an informed reply.

Why did I see your post in the sidebar? I asked a question last night. The reply was a comment that was less helpful than saying nothing, though I was surprised to find my question wasn't closed outright (I'm sure someone will get to it!) so I spent two hours trying to understand Microsoft source code that I came here for help understanding. I was on the site this morning to answer my own question because the people who knew the answer didn't bother reading it.

In one of the [comments above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396479/how-can-we-stop-failing-the-users-who-we-actually-want-to-join-and-remain-as-m?cb=1#comment774655_398173), someone demonstrates this far better than I could with a made up example.

> But honestly, "asking a question is really a last resort for me" should be your primary objective. Most questions have been asked.

So, according to an established user, asking a question should be a last resort. But according to the reputation page (one of the first pages I read):

> The three most important activities on Stack Overflow are **Asking**, Answering and Editing - none of which require any reputation at all!

Ah, so I can't comment until I get 50 rep, but I if I ask a question, it's closed for being a duplicate or something else, but I can't find any answered question that actually addresses my issue. I can't answer questions because I'm still learning, and the questions I've answered were abandoned by the asker (likely for reasons related to this discussion) and I have no reason to edit posts I don't know the answer to. So... what am I even doing here?

---

There's good discussion in other answers about the difference between being a site for beginners vs. professionals. That's an important element of this issue, but it seems to carry a lot of baggage, and it's related to this other element that may carry less.

People talk about curating "good questions". Note the lack of emphasis on curating *knowledge*. My question last night was about the use of a C# data structure in a particular use case, generalized as much as I could be relevant to other people. The comment I got in reply was to just read the source code. Meanwhile, the top post in the C# tag, with over 6,000 upvotes is "[What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c)". I can't think of a better example of a question that could be answered by a link to the MSDN, but I guess moderators found it interesting so it stayed and racked upvotes. Also in the top C# posts: *[Hidden features of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)* 1400 upvotes, 290 answers, locked because "this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format".

What I'm getting at may not be clear here, so to lay it out explicitly - **Stack Overflow does not curate *interesting* or *helpful* questions**. It curates questions that it deems *well-formed*, which sometimes lead to useful information.

Closed questions are obviously the biggest example of this. Regardless of individual reasons to close a question - consider, what's even the point? They still show up on google, but can't be answered, and they still show up in search so they don't streamline anything. Closing questions is a way for moderators to have fewer posts to moderate, and that way they can spend more time... closing questions.

The most helpful thing I've read about programming - ever - was a series of answers in response to an unanswered question, that was then closed in response to getting answers. The answerer dedicated multiple days to answering the question and providing code, examples, and illustrations. I dedicated multiple days to reading it to understand a topic that no other explanation had been able to clarify for me.

That user said they don't use the site anymore because questions have become uninteresting extremely specific questions and there's no interest in exploring and building knowledge together. That is the best representation of what this site is about.

You call people who want help without giving back "vampires", and you accuse Stack Overflow, Inc of trying to court them for profit, but where the hell do you think users like Scratte come from? No community grows by being *less inclusive*, you invite people in and see who sticks around and contributes. You maintain the quality of your community by encouraging the behavior you want to see. This site does nothing to encourage people who want to actually help other people. It only rewards people who want to help the site become more like it already is. It's a paperclip maximizer. On the technical end, the solutions are simple. Other answers have mentioned some. You'll know which ones they are because they're downvoted below zero and greyed out.

Stack Overflow doesn't want to help the users who want to join.

Comment: And so this leads to the big question: with 8000 questions a day, how can you make it effective for people to _answer_ questions? Because we could stop closing questions, that has massive impacts on the ability of things like the front page and similar questions lists to show more challenging questions to the people who can answer them. Is the ability to answer expert questions with current tooling what is in conflict with welcoming newbies?

Comment: Or are there alternatives to the front page for answering that would allow us to handle that? Because one of the key original reasons for the close system is it takes a lot less specific knowledge to know that something is not a question that will require expert answering than it does to answer such a question.

Comment: There are a variety of technical answers to those questions. For example, right now if you find an old unanswered question and answer it, you can often find it immediately get closed. Just automatically close or delete old questions that get no answers. Whatever. I didn't talk about the technical solutions because (especially here) people get bogged down in implementation details that don't matter. There's no technical problem here, there are cultural problems. (continued)

Comment: But those cultural problems are at least partially routed in technical solutions to the answering problem. There is a complex interplay where the way technical solutions to problems are implemented influences culture, and culture influences how those solutions are used.

Comment: Automatically removing old questions doesn't solve the problem because we need to get these questions out of answers views so they can focus on the ones they most effectively answer

Comment: Cultural problems: Everyone has a different idea of what the site is for. Any site with millions of users and a lot of volunteer moderation will run into that. So when you have those disagreements, you fall back on the rules and established norms. Except the rules are opaque, vague, and hard to find - and they're largely focused on the minutiae of how to write questions. So the rules lawyers win by default by virtue of having something concrete to point to and everyone gets stuck arguing about if we should call questions closed or hidden, or what the close workflow should be.

Comment: I the scale of stackoverflow, you can't effectively influence culture through discussions, but by shaping the interactions through the technical implementation of the site.

Comment: "Automatically removing old questions doesn't solve the problem" see this is what I was talking about in my next sentence. Any time I give a simple example, it's nitpicked and the actual point is completely ignored. I ended my comment with (continued) because I hit the character limit and I'm not using a text editor to proof my comments first, but you didn't bother waiting to see the rest of my thought. It's a perfect distillation of the SO experience.

Comment: I totally agree on the disagreement. It's just this answer doesn't convey that effectively.

Comment: " you can't effectively influence culture through discussions, but by shaping the interactions through the technical implementation of the site"
You can't influence culture with technical implementations until you decide *in what way* you want to influence the culture, otherwise you're just throwing sh*t at a wall to see what sticks. You've fixated on how to efficiently curate questions for answerers without discussing the core issue of what types of questions are being curated.

Comment: "It's a paperclip maximizer" made me laugh :) But you're right. The goal is not clear, the rules are vague and lacking consensus, and there's a huge backlog of stuff that only gets cleaned up when there's new activity. (I'm impressed that you only spent four hours to reach this though. I spent **a lot** longer.)

Comment: I'd say its a different view. What sort of questions do we want to curate because that is influenced by which ones we can build scalable answering workflows for. We can't just say we want to answer X types of problems, we need to work out if we can answer them as well. History has taught us that forums and newsgroups don't scale. What new alternative workflow do we have?

Comment: @Scratte Glad I could give someone a positive outcome with this :) 
Your explanation was really well written and helped me understand the site and what was frustrating me a lot. Standing on the shoulders of giants, as it were. Understanding the problem better sadly led me to the conclusion that it's not worth trying to become more involved, but seeing other people articulate the same issues at least made me feel like I wasn't alone, and that goes a long way.

Comment: @user1937198 Screws weren't invented because we had to find a use for screwdrivers.

Comment: To follow the analogy, crosshead screws where invented because of scaling issues with plain screwdrivers.

Comment: Re *"everyone has"*: Isn't that a bit exaggerated?

Comment: Re *"I can't answer questions because I'm still learning"*: You can. Some questions only require sufficient research, not own skill.

Comment: Re *"I have no reason to edit posts I don't know the answer to"*: If that is your criterion, then no. But in most cases it is more about fixing broken English in (otherwise good) questions. That doesn't require much programming skill (and [there are](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Javascript) [tools](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html)).

Comment: @Appleguysnake Thank you. In all honesty, this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398198/12695027) by [deceze ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/476) shows the real giant though :) It made me go "Ah! Eureka.."

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, it is a bit exaggerated. I felt it unnecessary to calculate the exact percentage of moderators with Monica in their name, and I thought it would sound like an awfully strange way of speaking. Your three comments are all technically correct and do nothing to address the point I was making. Another great example of why building rewards for grammatical corrections that don't change the content of a post doesn't help build knowledge. You get what you measure.

Comment: "people who knew the answer didn't bother reading it" You are jumping to conclusions. PS A solution is needed so askers of poor questions don't feel so bad, but allowing bad questions isn't it.

Answer (score 3):

**Me:** As a StackOverflow user, active since near the beginning of the site and with enough rep points for many of the moderation tools (my favorite is seeing deleted answers). I am barely active in meta, I moderate infrequently and although I go by the site rules, I don't agree with some of them, my perspective is as such...

**The past:** Initially the site was rather sparse and you could earn easy rep crumbs by answering questions for tags you are experienced in while helping users. Even then there were questions that looked like students asking people to solve their homework without any effort to think for themselves! Back then there weren't even easy tools for finding similar questions while asking, yet people voted down duplicates and discouraged people from answering without doing so.

**The present:** Nowadays ***some tags*** in the site are extremely saturated and questions are usually either duplicates or low quality (unclear, no attempt to solve by asker, missing vital details or wrongly tagged), while ***other tags***, usually new technologies and specialized technologies are sparse and questions usually go unanswered.

**How I use SO:** As SO is now so full of Q&A and as I now have less free time, I very rarely browse SO unless I have a question and even then I only look at unanswered questions with very interesting tags. **Feature idea** questions not answered in over a week.
***My main use*** for SO is to look for an answer for specific issues I find that the official documentation doesn't help with:

- If I find a relevant question with a relevant answer (whether selected or not), vote up (vote wildly-incorrect answers down), leave site.
- If I find a relevant question without a relevant answer, solve myself and then answer, vote question up (edit question first if necessary). (Vote wildly-incorrect answers down, vote partially useful answers up.)
- If I do not find a relevant question (or relevant question has an incorrect answer marked as correct), solve myself and then post question with answer. (I used to ask first, then solve myself, however, that hasn't helped in years - I'm not sure if this is SO fault or mine for looking for more complex things to do all the time.) If there are similar questions, I link them to my question and explain why they are irrelevant. If my answer can apply to them too, I link to my answer from a comment to those questions.

My **solution suggestion** for SO PMs (I never post a problem without attempting to think of a solution) is:

- For ***common tags*** give **less rep** e.g. 2 for question and 5 for answer instead of 10 and 10.
- For a combination of ***common tags*** and anonymous users or registered users for less than 2 years (or so):

  - don't enable answering for a period e.g. a few hours, to enable vote downs and flags. If the question ends up with a negative score, don't unfreeze it.
  - Make users look at a brief of first few similar questions and click on not relevant for each.
- For ***rare tags*** give higher rep on questions and answers e.g. 20 and 30 instead of now 10 and 10. - This will encourage accumulation new knowledge.
- For new users and for non-high rep users using tags they haven't used in the past, show the user a message per tag with usage correct and common-incorrect guidelines e.g. `asp.net mvc` is to be used for questions regarding `asp.net` controllers, **not** for database questions in an asp.net application.

P.S. Most of my meta post got voted down, just saying!

Comment: What is a **rare tag** ? If a tag is not used much (rare) and deals with mostly obsolete technology and/or quirky software, why would answering there merit more ("20 and 30 instead of now 10 and 10") ?

Comment: Potentially we could also boost how long rare tags stay on the home page as well?

Comment: @SepRoland rare is something more specific than c++, java, python, c#, scala like spark-streaming, github-actions, something that requires more trial and error and less just read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Where does one speak like an actual human, to share an experience without having to frame it as a question or an answer. How do I express I got to be disengaged through what I have seen on the site. I used this space to explain how I got to this point and got downvoted, presumably for the mess that would result from my suggested fixes which were put there to attempt to form answer to the main question, but the main drive to start to answer was in response to:

> What was your reaction to that answer? Sadness? Shame? Despair?

Highly structured, regulated communication and empathy aren't necessarily compatible. For a emotionally driven question I've received a clinical response and so have others on this thread while talking about our own experiences.

I've only just discovered the discussion tag but would never think to use it. Possibly because SO had trained me not to ask opinion based questions.

For people like me, I want a "chat now" option where a bunch of people from meta can direct me to knowledge, I'm trying to find guidance on something and my searches haven't found what I want but I'm sure its obvious to you guys that breathe it. Fine, promote it to a duplicate to help with signposting/search results later. I just don't want the fear of being downvoted or told to research while actively trying to be a good user. I also want the ability to stop the conversation when I want out, once the answer is found, thanks, you helped, now I'll go away and use that info for good.

For newbie devs: Forum style is at odds with the SO drive for a single question with a single answer (great to skim and get answers or decide it isn't helpful and great for SEO), SO is trying to be a textbook/quick cheats for cut paste, which is it's strength with thousands of authors but we forget the questions stem from people needing help immediately, and haven't found it elsewhere.
There is a desire to help users and there is definitely a demand for this kind of help, considering the hostility to a forum style site, an utterly different site with less standards so mods that specifically want to avoid this task don't have to engage with it. Answers with this idea in seem massively downvoted alternative is to *just let users go elsewhere*, like https://javaranch.com/

original :

### Completely unsurprised by that experience, you don't necessarily grow out of feeling like a "new user".

**Problem: SO seems unwelcoming to new questioners**

IRL there'd be a room with teachers where you could drop in and say "Hey, here's my problem, SO said here is the answer but I can't figure out how to put it together". So maybe that would be a way to appear kinder, the convo would auto delete in a few days, any missing content added to the post marked as the original of the duplicate. Your well meaning "help vampires" could hang out there, not suggesting rep given, some people just like chatting.

---

**Problem: Losing mod engagement**

Improve the ramp up from Suggested Edit review to Close/Reopen possibly train in close queue so it prepares you for the reopen queue. That's when I stopped.

Apparently I am a mod, I don't feel like one, the ability to close/reopen seems IMPORTANT but I'm not involved in that anymore. I just treat SO like a wiki and just improve poorly worded answers or make the code able to compile. I joined out of altruism and desire to help out so the next person finds answer easier than I did.

Suggested edits review queue - I felt well prepared to be able to tackle it, I was trained to edit posts to get rep, and then I got to review edits and remember when my edits were rejected or improved upon when I didn't have the rep to make edits autonomously.

Once I got enough rep for the open/close review queue... it's a much bigger jump, while looking into a question and it's edits and possible proposed duplicate it would be closed. I didn't see how people could make those decisions so quickly. I remember being convinced of a robo-closer (I have no proof, vague memories). It wasn't worth my time, checking my account I only managed to vote twice, which is not representative of the time I spent on it. I felt bad for the questions that seemed to be closed out of hand. Or maybe they knew something I didn't.

---

**Problem: Meta being unhelpful**

I agree with condensing of information suggested by [Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394890/70345), I just asked a meta question, to check my understanding. Honestly I expect meta to be a bit more chill as I was actively seeking info about the site to be a better user and was happy to close question as soon as I got something useful.

I asked a question because in this pool of people, each brain is a link table of knowledge about the correct term to search, it's a choice of ask or never find. I went in completely ready to be corrected. After agreeing to close as dedupe I still got comments I consider users as going out of their way to defend the site from criticism from an earnest question.

A lot of effort goes into asking a question, it's the last resort, and you brace yourself. If you expected negativity and read it into every interaction, you will find it. Would I feel differently if I read them in a different tone of voice?

Is the answer to rate responses on how attacking they feel so users are aware how they are being received? I can see that being a disaster, communication is so nuanced and offence taken based on the receivers state of mind, not just the communicator's intent. "Earnest" question emoji vs "I'm being facetious" emoji? All of it should be dealt under "be kind".

---

**Optional reading, why SO is scary:**

As a numbers game it's easy to explain SO being intimidating. My actions (decisions/posts) are scrutinised by multiple people, any of them having knowledge or experience I lack which is relevant to my action. Viewed as a whole, those individuals become SO, the all-knowing, all critiquing beast.

Only today have I realised my opinion SO of being unkind was formed by doing that queue. I think that queue let me see how brand new users were treated. Immediate down votes, multiple edits, some completely changing the meaning of the question, then closed as dupe based on the new meaning. Not to mention comments telling people for homework questions or to use google. It was less my own experience of asking, but seeing hundreds of others. I'd try to improved edits and then find the question had been closed in the meantime as off topic. Not all the tine and there are genuine bad questions, I don't want to debate the issues of bad faith/low effort questions, I think seeing so many users that needed a bit more explanation how to adapt an existing question to the problem they actually faced.

Comment: To your IRL analogy - I work for a large university.  Of all the ~40,000 students on the campus at any given point, there's maybe a fraction of those students (lets's say 5% to make the numbers easier) who are concerned with a Comp-Sci problem.  Of those 5% and building off of my time as a tutor on campus, 5% of that population are interested in seeking 1 on 1 help with a problem and will readily approach people with a question.  That means that's about 100 people looking for help which is why 1 on 1 works.

Comment: In Stack Overflow's case, it's the entire 40,000 students who are concerned with Comp-Sci, and all 40,000 students who are concerned with a Comp-Sci problem, and all 40,000 people who are seeking 1 on 1 guidance.  [We get something on the order of 8K questions *per day*](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), and there's really not enough people who are volunteering to help 8K potential question askers.  So, the IRL-like guidance is simply not available, and for your sake as well as mine, I wish that someone set that expectation earlier.

Comment: @Makoto Just seeing these no rep users flailing with not quite enough knowledge to put things together thinking SO is somewhere to get help, we just let them go and hope they will try again or not. It would be a mess of a chat room, but if you ask what is missing, it's that all convo is high-stakes, public, voted on, and semi-permanent. I agree with all of your points. While trying to solve one problem you can introduce another, so you may decide to sick with the current situation.

Comment: The problem with the forum proposal is that stackoverflow killed most of the forums. So something everyone proposing a forum needs to answer is: Why would people ask questions on such a forum rather than stackoverflow proper? And who would be answering on this forum that isn't already active on the forums that still exist for various languages?

Comment: Is it more welcoming to tell people they need to meet the quality standards, or to effectively shadow ban them?

Comment: If this is about finding a way to cater to new devs then do that, or don't & close their Qs. If it's about motivating me to stay+do maintenance-not helping new devs demotivated me. I'd push the closed Q elsewhere then answer, SO uncluttered but they got help. I can't dm AFAIK. People aren't always aware of what they don't know and fail to make a good SO question. It might just boil down to a logic issue w/out knowing what tools exist. i.e. combining loops, switch/if statements while not knowing loops exist. If that's a bad eg, it's because I've disengaged, not modded & dropped that expertise

Answer (score -4):

Managing Q&A sites, SE must pay homage - actively and ubiquitously - to the credo that **no answer can be better than the question that prompted it**.

So, where are the rewards for good questions? Of course, a good question will have its reward in a good - and prompt - answer, but that's not how one teaches newbies to ask good questions. In fact, this answer is 30 years old now and might do with a little reform.

Why don't we think of a checklist to go with every question?

- Is the question's title descriptive?
- Does the question include all required detail?
- Can the question be answered with yes or no?
- Is it expressed in English?
- Say, 12 to 20 questions,
  certainly not all the same for all forums and all subjects!

The user is requested to answer the questions. For each answer he gets points. Before he posts he is advised, "You obtained only 2 out of 15 possible points. Giving your question a higher rating will prompt more experts to answer. Do you want to answer more questions in the check list?"

The rating of the question is published with it and may affect the points awarded to the selected solution. But obviously, most members who answer questions will know from the rating how good the question is before they look at it. Some they may not want to waste their time on.

The checklist can be called up from the question and members can up or down-vote each check mark the user set. If the title is "I need help" and the user thought this to be a "descriptive title", down-vote it. Perhaps a comment can be added, too.

Anyway, the format of the checklist would permit integration of the current "How to ask a good question" into it. There could be a link next to "Is the question's title descriptive?" that opens a text box with the applicable rules and suggestions.

The point is that the user earns points for thinking about his question. The more he thinks the more he earns. The more points he earned the higher will be the esteem in which his question is held by members.

Most members are as appreciative of good questions as they are resentful of the careless ones. Down-voting fraudulently earned points (points granted for calling "I need help" a descriptive title) results in a down-grading of the question via its rating. The user can see his points dwindling. He can look at the checklist and see which of his check marks caused the ire, maybe also see some irrate comments (not under his question but in the check list, not with regard to his question but in response to his statement *about* his question).

A question that collected too many down-votes is closed. The record that led to the closing would be much better than the current "3 strikes and you're out" system. The reasons members select from there are notoriously ill-fitted to purpose.

But it isn't only down-votes that are collected. Good questions get up-votes, too. Proficient users can earn more points for asking than the members get who answer. For the pool from which SE hopes to attract new members that is important.

Only by placing the question at the center of what SE does, not the expert who answers them, can SE rejuvenate itself and play on the advantage its sheer size affords it.

Comment: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/215552)?

Comment: Your bolded credo has been proven wrong time and again on Stack Overflow. But, yes, we recognize that questions are important. That's why we now reward them equally as much as answers.

Comment: Does not compute: *"points granted for calling "I need help" a descriptive title"*. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I believe this parenthetical harkens back to an earlier sentence regarding descriptive titles and the fact that "I need help" is not one. The user appears to be suggesting individual voting on each checked item of a potential checklist for a given question. So, a user who votes up the checked item "title is descriptive" on a post titled "I need help" is getting "fraudulently earned points".

Comment: @Cody Gray My "bolded credo has been proven wrong time and again". No it hasn't. By definition, an answer that is "better" than the question it purports to answer may be a good guess but it isn't an answer. What has been proven time and again is that the effort to guess what the OP wants goes wrong more often than right. Successful marketing strategy can't be built on faulty analysis. I suggest to place the question in the center of what we do. You wish to maintain the current expert-centered approach and perhaps improve it. These are real choices with different futures.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Whether or not "I need help" is a descriptive title is a matter of opinion. On StackOverflow, where I spend my time, it's not. I suggest to grant points to the OP for placing an affirming check mark. I suggest to give him improved access to help (different for each forum) to allow him to judge. And I want other users to take back the points if they judge that the OP didn't make a good and fair decision.

Answer (score -8):

The goals of Stack Overflow go counter to helping newbies. From /about:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

The thing is, most first-timers don't come here looking for "questions about programming". Instead, they come here to look for someone to either solve a problem for them or to debug their code. They are often desperate, self-taught, and/or have really lousy teachers. They shouldn't be penalized for any of that.

I downvote a lot of those questions because that's what I think Stack Overflow wants me to do. It wants me to help build a repository of generally useful questions and answers. We reward good questions and penalize the bad ones so that the cream rises to the top. It's our civic duty to downvote crappy questions into oblivion -- a very user-unfriendly thing to do.

My recommendation (and I know I'm not the only one to have suggested this) is to have a `mentor.stackoverflow.com` site (or pick your favorite name) where all "please fix my code" questions are routed to. The expressed goal of that site should not be to build a library of detailed answers, but instead to *help individuals*. Questions on that site last no longer than a week.

No question should be off-limits no matter how poorly written or how many times the same question has been asked. No question should be marked as a duplicate (though links to originals can appear in answers), no question should be closeable by anybody except perhaps the question-asker. In short, it should be more like (parts of) [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) once was - a place for people to get friendly help.

The way I see it working is something like this:

1. Some new user asks "why do I get 'variable doesn't exist?" or "what does 'file not found' mean? The file is clearly there!" along with a link to a screenshot of an IDE with a tiny out-of-focus error message with the right margin chopped off.
2. One of us recognizes this as a cry for help, so we move this question to `mentor.stackoverflow.com`, where we collectively apply absolutely tremendous amounts of peer pressure to help and be nice. We offer advice but don't require that the question be rewritten before we are willing to help (though it is fair to ask for clarification).

Note: we need to work *hard* to make sure this is seen as a *service* rather than a *punishment*. They aren't being "banished", they are being treated as an honored first-time or casual visitor.

3. The question is annotated with a banner explaining the difference between stackoverflow.com and mentor.stackoverflow.com, offers encouragement, and provides links to help them learn how to write good questions. It should explain that learning how to ask questions is itself a skill that needs to be learned and improved upon, and improving that skill will be rewarded with reputation on Stack Overflow.
4. After a few days to maybe no more than a week, and *if* the question appears to be unique and useful, and the OP shows some effort into improving their question, and there is a selected answer that at least one other person has upvoted, one of us can move the question back to the main site. At that point, question-asker and accepted answerer gets a huge pile of points for being willing to improve their question and learn from the advice they've been given.
5. *If* the user doesn't put forth any effort, no harm, no foul, no downvotes. Once the question is a week old with no more edits, it is quietly and permanently deleted.

Comment: I'm curious who you expect to frequent such a site.  It reminds me an awful lot of forums; the very thing SO was created to replace.

Comment: @fbueckert: That's a fair question. I expect people who like helping other people will frequent that site. There are a lot of people who enjoy helping absolute newbies.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't hold out a lot of hope that that is sustainable; it quickly devolves into expertise burnout, a flood of, "help me now!" questions, and eventually, the death of the site.  You can see that in any tech support forum prior to SO.

Comment: @fbueckert: we already have a flood of "help me now!" questions. This helps with that problem by giving us a place to move them so that they don't clutter up stackoverflow. And since they are automatically deleted after a week on this proposed side, I don't see that as a problem. Thanks for the feedback, though.

Comment: You lost me at: "_No question should be off-limits no matter how poorly written or how many times the same question has been asked. No question should be marked as a duplicate (though links to originals can appear in answers), no question should be closeable by anybody except perhaps the question-asker._".  This place would become a red hot mess.

Comment: @mickmackusa: I think you missed the point. "this place" would not become a red hot mess. It already is a red hot mess of those types of questions. The point is to move those to a _different_ site specifically designed for these types of questions, and they would automatically be deleted in a very short time if not improved. Thanks for the feedback, though.

Comment: My Stack Overflow a̶d̶d̶i̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ volunteerism is already stretched to the upper limit while monitoring the SE sites that I care about.  Having yet another cluster of content only forces my attention to spread further.

Comment: `help.stackoverflow.com` already exists. It is `stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes`

Comment: @philipxy: I understand what you are saying, but what you suggest isn’t what I had in mind.

Answer (score -9):

Make some effort to actually encourage them.

I want to add another answer that's a bit more actionable and optimistic than my first (which I still stand by). Again, this is from the perspective of a new user with <100 rep who has made several attempts to get more involved but has been discouraged by the site.

Most of my issues with this site come from power users who view bad questions and new users as an irritation to be removed, rather than humans who need help (e.g. "help vampires"). However there is one frustration with new users I share, which is that it can be very annoying to spend time trying to help a new user who then never returns, upvotes you, accepts your answer, or might even downvote you if they don't like your answer.

In considering solutions to this problem, the consensus among power users seems to be once again to treat new users as pests. Popular solutions seem to be banishing questions to some "beginner" site (heavyhanded, but not unreasonable), immediately closing questions without *actually reading* them, downvoting questions without reading or voting to close, villifying se inc for trying to grow the userbase and be inclusive, and a variety of other ways to punish new users for not having "good" questions. This is where I differ.

The design of the site does little to encourage helping someone find an answer if they have a "boring" question, and less if you're not helping by giving them an answer that will be upvoted. In trying to give back to the site (and earn comment privileges), I've answered a number of simple beginner questions, which were almost all ignored, and the one I put the most effort into was actually downvoted. I understand the frustration that comes with that. But as I continue to learn about the site the problem clearly isn't the new users (who are acting reasonably from their side of things).

If I look at a page of beginner questions and everything I think I can answer already has an unaccepted answer, there's little incentive for me to go through them all and see if the answer is any good because I know there's a high chance the OP will never return. We need to shift the burden of maintaining questions and answers away from beginners (and moderators!!) and create incentives for everyone to work through the queues and *actually help people*.

Every time I give an example it's nitpicked to death, so I'm going to give as many examples as I can to try and make it clear that the examples are just examples and the larger idea of distributing that responsibility is the point. So, in no particular order:

- Create a system to *automatically* mark questions as "abandoned" (not
  trying to create more moderation queues). Raise the bar for marking a
  question abandoned according to the OP's rep. So a question by a 1
  day old user would be marked abandoned in a day, maybe 100 rep 3
  days, 500 7 days, and then >1000 1 month.

Once you have that system you could use it any number of ways.

- Abandoned questions with one answer automatically give the answer +10 (don't mark it accepted, just give rep)
- AND/OR abandoned questions are automatically closed if the user doesn't return in a week or a month or whatever.
- AND/OR create a badge for answering a lot of questions that are later abandoned ("newbie helper", "patient" - I see "Tenacious" and "unsung hero" exist, but they require zero-score answers to be 20% of your answers, and you can't get them if someone else upvotes your answers, which I want to encourage!)
- AND/OR give something like +5 rep if you're the first/only comment, the OP replies (usually "oh that's it, thanks!") and then abandons the question
- AND/OR other ideas. You get the point. Hopefully.

Aside from abandoned questions being annoying to experienced users, people new to the site might only have the knowledge to help beginners. So if they want to contribute, they're forced to deal with the table scraps that experienced users don't want to be bothered with, which isn't fun! And there's not much in the design (or culture!) to encourage doing it if you don't have to. Same for more experienced users who just may have more patience and enjoy helping beginners.

- Offer some small reward to answers on questions that were closed or marked as duplicates
- Create some way to encourage writing a sentence or two when closing something as a duplicate. Lots of users here complain that questions they've closed as duplicates are edited with a comment like "it's not a duplicate". Well of course! Lots of questions are closed as dupes because whoever voted/closed it only read the title or the first sentence. There should be a small reward for, say, giving a short answer that has a checkbox labeled "mark as duplicate". Reward or not, the site should have some way to clearly encourage saying "This is a duplicate of this question because you're trying to x". Yes, you will still have lots of people complaining. You will also have lots of people learning and therefore becoming better users of the site in the future.

I recently created my first self-answered question because the most common question in [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) had no decent answer I could point to for duplicates. As far as I know, there's no encouragement (outside of just getting upvotes) to create canonical questions.

- This is a weird one, but similar to the bounties system, create a bounty button (name it what you want) that essentially functions as "This question is simple and asked all the time and it annoys me, but I don't have the time or inclination to create a canonical question myself". You can pay 10 rep when you hit the button and it gets added to a pool with a keyword or a question you write and goes on a bounties board. Use a related feature to let people match their bounty to a pool that may already exist. Maybe auto-create a question that anyone (or people who have paid into the bounty) can edit or at least comment on to collectively flesh out the question. Only people who voted on the bounty can accept, or moderators, or whatever there's plenty of ways to handle that part. Actually that might be my best suggestion so far, but it has too much detail so I expect to hear why it'll never work.

Somewhat following from that idea, many of these conversations talk about the problems with "stackoverflow" as an entity and how the site gets "8000 questions a day". This is a site for every programming language in existence. I do not think anyone is an expert or even interested in all of them. As I mentioned in my other answer, technical solutions to problems at this scale already exist. Having those solutions means nothing if the culture of the site has no interest in using them. Obviously culture is hard to change, but **an easy start is to remove the assumption that [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) programmers working on factory automation are ever going to feel compelled to moderate or improve questions by teenagers making [roblox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox) mods**.

To that end, the site needs changes that reduces the scale of the problem. The experienced users again seem to want to do this by telling newbies to f-k off and getting angry at the company for ever trying to encourage growth. Cool if you want to have the digital equivalent of a high school clique, but that doesn't seem to be anyone's actual desire. Mostly it seems like newbies want help and veterans just want to see less stuff that annoys them. Those aren't really opposing concepts!

- Don't treat the site as a monolith. When I go to the front page, show me only my watched tags, similar to how Reddit lets you subscribe to subreddits. This concept already exists for Stack Exchange, it can be applied here without making new sites.
- Obviously that means I'll never see questions that might interest me if they happen to be tagged wrong, or I'll have to add a million tags. Again, there are a billion potential solutions to this.

  - Don't strictly filter, but do more to promote my watched tags. Give me 80% watched tags, 20% other
  - Create meta-tags and filter the front page that way. If I've watched [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) then throw everything from `C-like` on my front page. If I've watched [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) then throw everything from `gamedev-general` on there.
  - The "Hot Network Questions" sidebar is great. I love reading weird interesting questions from communities I never knew existed. It's a big part of why I started trying to use Stack Exchange again. Do something similar for questions within SO itself.
  - Do the same for moderation tools if they don't already. I don't know much about them and I assume there's a way to filter by tags, but the point is to encourage people to take responsibility for a specific part of the garden, rather than the entire park.

That finally brings me to my favorite part. Lots of people suggest creating a StackOverflow Beginners site, but that comes with lots of technical problems. Again, why not just use the tools we have?

- I was going to suggest automatically tagging questions by new users with a special tag, but they have that note telling you to be nice, so this functionality already exists! It's just not being used very much.
- Let everyone - or high rep users - filter out questions from new accounts. I can see why this isn't done - we want new users to get answers. But let's be honest, the people who want to banish new users to a beginners site aren't interested in helping newbies anyway.
- Like the suggestions above, create incentives for answering questions from new users

  - +10 for positive score or accepted answer on a user's first question.
  - `Ambassador` badge for answering some number of questions from new users
  - `Guidance Counselor` badge for accepted answers to a new user who becomes a moderator
  - `Some other name` badge for accepted answers to some # of new users who go on to become active users instead of asking one question and leaving (OP gets 1k rep, or stays active for a year, or joins another SE site, or whatever)
  - If you answer 50 questions from new users only then do you earn the privilege to hide posts from new users :p
- You can also use the new user flag to tweak certain moderation tools that people complain about a lot. Maybe those rules and messages about closing questions that everyone loves to argue about apply differently to questions from new users vs established users.

I actually had a lot of fun coming up these ideas and especially the badges. It's wild how many people seem to prefer designing new sticks to hit people with instead of new carrots.

Comment: There are a few things about your post that I don't think is accurate. I'm not sure users that close Questions "only read the title or the first sentence". I also don't think that anyone is out to get new users, like you say with "power users seems to be once again to treat new users as pests". However, there is friction and I know it's frustrating getting a Question closed. I agree that some comments are quite harsh and I really don't like the "What have you done so far?" comment. But the comment is often valid, though I think it should be phrased differently.

Comment: I think perhaps it feels lonely here, because most of the help one gets here is self-help. And comments are asking for improvements. In my case only a few users have been rude to me, but it wasn't centered on my first week. I posted a Question once. It didn't get a lot of attention and no comments, no Answers. It didn't make me feel abandoned though. I just assumed it was because no one could answer, or no one wanted to.

Comment: It shouldn't matter that a new user doesn't return. If the Question is fine, then your Answer will help others. The point is not to answer Questions that aren't OK. I spend a fair amount of time helping users get their Questions in shape, only to see them leave it midway if anyone provides an Answer. Of course it's a different kind of frustration.

Comment: I try to answer with runnable code. I've come to also explain why/how it works or solves the issue, and I've had good responses to them with this approach. Comments are meant to be deleted at any time, so you're not likely to get support for reputation on those. (I expect these ones here to go at any time :)

Comment: About cleaning up: We have [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) :) It's a program that cleans up abandoned Questions. ..and I think you're confusing meta bagdes with main badges. Example [Unsung on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero) and [Unsung on main](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero).

Comment: @Scratte Hey it's you! You're right I see that I was on the wrong page for the unsung hero badge (I removed that line) and it's good to see lots of people have it! But the other badge criteria I was talking about (or any variation on the general idea I was getting at) still stands.

Comment: The Roomba thing is interesting, and it uses similar terminology/criteria to what I proposed, but it's like the new user flag in that it doesn't really do anything particularly useful with it to address the cause. All it does is clean up search results, it does nothing to encourage people to help prevent questions being abandoned. And it only does this with questions over a month or a year old if they weren't closed, which makes sense for auto-deleting, but leaves a ton of time that abandoned questions are just sitting around.

Comment: Of course I'm being slightly hyperbolic in places here when describing veteran users, but I'm just talking about the the type of users who do indeed do that. Obviously #notallusers only read the first line of your question, but I've had it happen to me and I've seen it on other people's questions where reading three sentences made it clear that their question was different than the duplicate it was linked to.

Comment: I feel like there's some sense that my posts (and others) are due to some bitterness about a question that got closed or one interaction, but remember that this is an answer to a question that refers to people as "help vampires". I've written documentation that went ignored and contributed to lots of internet communities. I get what the term means, but saying "how can we stop failing new users" and then calling new users by a disparaging name and every new user who posts a suggestion is downvoted really feels like it supports my characterization of the prevailing attitude.

Comment: "I spend a fair amount of time helping users get their Questions in shape, only to see them leave it midway if anyone provides an Answer." This is the kind of behavior that I was trying to think of ways to encourage! You did all that work, then got frustrated because the OP left. But you said "it shouldn't matter that a new user doesn't return". The site's priorities are torn. It wants to curate every question ever asked, but they have to come from somewhere. So we need to consider the incentives of the people on both sides, who don't care about the same things.

Comment: @Appleguysnake Stack Overflow is already getting more questions than it can handle, as shown by [the size of the close vote review queue](/review/close/stats). Discouraging new users is actually a good thing from the curation perspective (which I share)

Comment: Fix link in above post: I meant to point to [the queue on main](//stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats), not on meta

Comment: What I meant is that it shouldn't matter that a user never returns when you decide to Answer a Question, however most users that never return also didn't ask a good Question. Or they left it half fixed. As I'm sure you know, it takes time and energy to make good content. If a user leaves because they got the answer and not caring that their Question is a mess, and can't be bothered to fix it. then perhaps it's not a loss that they chose to not come back.

Comment: As for "help vampires", I don't like the term, but having to continuously rewrite your Answer because someone keeps scope-creeping (changing their Question) isn't doing the site a favor. The original good Question is lost and I as an answerer feels more like I'm a free service to just this one user. That's just not right. It doesn't happen much anymore though, as I can spot it now and if/when it does happen, I know how to deal with it: I mostly just just explain how the site work, and for the most part, they rollback their own Question, and ask a new one with the new requirements.

Comment: BTW: I reckon you don't care too much about votes (at least on meta), but in case you do, any criticism about other users behavior is likely better received if it's 1. Supported by facts and 2. Unemotional and most importantly: Not attacking them. It's almost like giving feedback to new users ;)

Comment: @pppery I addressed this in my answer. There are plenty of ways to deal with the size of the close queue, including making it less important. But the userbase seems to prefer discouraging new users over just trying out new tools and ideas - even if those new things are still working toward the goals they have for the site. Which is weird in the context of this question about encouraging new users, but I suppose it's normal for humans to be full of contradictory desires.

Comment: @Scratte You're correct, though I would care more if there was a welcoming culture. I promise my post was not "emotional", I just wrote it up because it's an interesting design problem I wanted to think through, and I thought there was a chance that specific implementation ideas (which *were* supported by facts!) would be more well-received. I didn't attack anyone, I just described the attitudes I saw - you'll note the other commenter here said that discouraging new users is a good thing. The post below mine is short, friendly and just describes a simple idea. It got an even worse reaction.

Comment: @Appleguysnake On meta, votes are often just a sign of agreement/disagreement. Nothing to worry about :)

Comment: You jump to ((very) wrong) conclusions about the experienced users' view.

Answer (score -10):

I hope this is the right place to write my experience, and what can be done...

I just answered some questions and got frustrated, really fast (in a few hours!) even with an accepted answer in one of my first answers.

I shall not waste your time. Here is what to do:

1. User (will call it M after that sentence) logs in to Stack Overflow.
2. M starts upvoting and downvoting content directly. There isn't any need to have badges.
3. The system starts filtering the content, which M can modify the thresholds of content that is filtered.
4. The system is trained with real people, who works for or manages Stack Overflow, so that abusive users can easily be detected, by a not-very-complicated algorithm. (Abusive users are the ones trying to benefit from the system, in price of being harmful to other members and the Stack Overflow platform, say, by downvoting appreciated questions / answers.)
5. There's no need to ban any post or user. Just give the control of M's own decisions' results.
6. To get a better result, M should continue downvoting and upvoting... Which helps the system cluster M in a much better (or worse) class, M deserved.

In summary, give M the user experience that M deserves. ***Personalize the results***!

Hope I could be clear and welcoming. I see that the real Stack Overflow will be much better, because the roots are already strong. Have a nice day :)

Comment: So... you are saying that rather than *deleting* content that fails to meet our standards, we should let users set their own standards and choose to see garbage if they want to? Why would anyone want to? Why would this help the platform?

Comment: When we use the term AI , it still seems to be a big , difficult thing, but the control can be done this way. People will use the platform , however they benefit it. This is how life is , and is supposed to be. 

If the system lets the users to do something, they will. Why don't we focus on the thing that we can achieve , instead of going after impossible solutions , especially when data grows ?

Comment: - we should let users set their own standards and choose to see garbage if they want to? 

Think about the opposite way : 
we should let users set their own standards and choose to see quality content , which they deserve..

Comment: as an example , someone downvoted my solution, current situation: M who would think my solution is useful will not be able to see my solution in first place. After personalizing , M will be able to see the solution , after downvoting and upvoting some other content. Sure the second case is more acceptable , for me . –

Comment: AI is a replacement for humans. We have actual humans who know how to program that can judge the quality of content, so why use an AI? The "authority" here is the community. This site is only what it is because we have quality standards. If you *really* wanted "anything goes", you'd be asking on Yahoo Answers instead.

Comment: Let me add redidit and Quora to that list.

Comment: "someone downvoted my solution, current situation: M who would think my solution is useful will not be able to see my solution in first place." No, people can still see your answers even if they've been downvoted. They may have to scroll a bit further to see them, but they're still there. And if they don't *want* to scroll down and see the downvoted answers, then... well, they're setting their own quality control standards, just like you want.

Comment: If you really want to compare my solution with other projects, quora and yahoo has nothing to do with that, but youtube does! 
Go to youtube and start voting up and down , you will see that a few minutes later , you will be facing the content , which you were looking for , but not aware if that was existing .

Comment: @F1Krazy , "No, people can still see your answers even if they've been downvoted. They may have to scroll a bit further to see them, but they're still there. "

Nope, one of my posts were deleted in minutes , in SO , which is closed , downvoted (very fast ) , flagged ... Why do i feel that i am being alienated ? Are you honest about what you wright? I really don't want to waste my , or anyone else's time . I have things to do, which is important.  i will possibly not answer more comments . Some commenters just comment with memorized cliché answers .This is just wasting time.

Comment: There is no correlation between downvotes and deletions. An answer can get dozens of upvotes and still get deleted (I've seen it happen), or it can get dozens of downvotes and still remain on the site. "Are you honest about what you wright?" 100%.

Comment: "I really don't want to waste my , or anyone else's time." Strict quality control takes care of that part.

Comment: @F1K An answer with a 0 or higher vote tally cannot be directly deleted (except by a diamond moderator). All answers, regardless of the vote tally, will be deleted if the question is deleted for any reason.  Once an answer has a negative vote tally, some privileged volunteers may vote to delete the answer -- the deletion requires 3 delete votes.  So, there is a relationship between downvotes and deletion.

Answer (score -17):

## Stack Overflow (Still) Needs a Separate but Related (Official) Forum for New Users

I *still* really think that 'inverting' the 'workflow' of the site for new users would be the best solution:

- [Add 'related' forums for questions that don't belong here - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254563/add-related-forums-for-questions-that-dont-belong-here)

The way that 'question' linked above is worded is a little unclear for my current meaning. The idea is that *all* questions (for new users or users without 'sufficient' reputation, whatever that is) would *start* in the official Stack Overflow *forum*. The 'good' (best) questions would be migrated to the main site, i.e. curated.

A Stack Overflow forum would be a perfect place for people to seek help and *possibly* contribute to The Canon of questions and answers on the main site. Most new 'questions' on such a forum could be answered, or at least the asker helped, by linking to existing SO questions (and their answers). Almost all of them could be further helped by being encouraged to clarify their questions, produce a minimal reproducible example, and guided towards general advice about debugging or troubleshooting on their own, as well as being given tips on researching questions (e.g. about error messages) themselves. All of that activity is much more appropriate to a forum than to a Q&A site (with such high standards as we have).

So, instead of allowing anyone to ask a question here and then closing or downvoting the 'bad' ones, allow those same people to ask their questions in an environment in which there *are no* 'bad' questions and then *reward* them for asking (very) good questions by 'featuring' them on the main site.

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398120/173497) to this same Meta question is correct insofar as the (main) Stack Overflow site is (ideally) a "question museum". Most of the drama related to bad feelings of newish (and veteran) users pertains to The Deluge of questions that *aren't good enough* to be 'exhibited in the museum'.

So, instead of making most users feel bad for not being able to contribute something good enough for 'the museum' immediately, let them ask for help in *a more suitable venue* (first).

Comment: Reminds me of https://javaranch.com/ where as a "greenhorn" I helped people that were a week into programming while I was only a month into it. I agree there is a desire to help users and there is demand for this kind of help, reading this page, maybe an utterly different site with less standards so mods that specifically want to avoid this task don't have to engage with it. Forum style is at odds with the SO drive for a single question with a single answer (great, and good SEO, quick skim to get the answer), it's trying to be a textbook with thousands of authors and people needing help

Comment: @ono2012 Why can't that place be places like javaranch? Maybe the community needs a list of sites that do offer 1:1 guided help that we can point people at.

Comment: @user1937198 That – maintaining a list of other sites – was *also* shot down (in another series of questions on Meta). The effective 'consensus' is that SO 'must' work on its own roughly as-is (tho a significant part of that same 'consensus' is that it will continue to NOT work). SO the business seems to *need* more and more new users, and *wants* them to not be so unhappy; SO the site (i.e. the actual users) remains locked in a (losing) battle against the onslaught of new users (and their 'bad' questions).

Comment: @user1937198 yeah, it can be. Being nice/helpful+SO's USP are incompatible. SO's strength is a clear problem&solution with easy cut paste code. Achieved by avoiding mounds of duplicated effort, everything redirected to a single place for polish. That can't cater to new devs, so add a mechanism to provide for them or accept SO doesn't help new devs. Sending them to javaranch would be an improvement as they'd have a chance at getting an answer. Your suggestion is a true solution. But have we solved a Q that wasn't asked? Was this Q about learning SO rules? (rhetorical, response optional) :)

Comment: Although this has -16 rep (I upvoted), I completely agree. I wish there was a section where I could focus on coding rather than reputation points.

Answer (score -18):

Particularly new users need extra supervision. In the case of salvageable posts, always the non-destructive options should be done.

1. The most typical, that a user posts a comment/question/answer as a different post type. These are typically quickly deleted: comments posted as answers can be converted to a comment, but it happens only rarely (it requires mod intervention). The other 5 conversion types are even technically impossible.
2. Unfortunately, migrating off-topic questions to their intended site is close to be impossible (it would require the same votes by all the 3 required close voters, or mod intervention). The closure of the question with the reason "go to re-post it on site X" is a clear signature of incompetence (any sane user would think this: *"Why the ... you can not move my post there?"* or *"You are advertising other sites to me, what are you doing?"*). Instead of generating a negative experience in the newbie with 1 sites, a quick and seamless migration would create a positive experience with 2 sites.
3. The system actually *rewards* unexplained downvoting, because it is the only way to avoid revenge downs. That warning box is the school example of a lip service - not advices should be given to the reviewers, but real rewards. An obvious solution would be to give a higher strength for the explained downs (or a weaker to the unexplained ones). This is perfectly surreal for both the company and for the wonderful the meta community.

*Unfortunately, not even the company has any idea, what is this post about, just like our most wonderful meta voters.*

So, in my opinion, the current system, without radical changes, is unsalvageable and there is no way to attract more users. There is some way to attract more crap, and it works for a while.

Comment: Many new users "need" help to post a question that belongs here, but that doesn't mean this is the place to get that help. Of course, SO Inc doesn't want to alienate them, so they "need" a solution to that.

Comment: @philipxy Yeah. But the important thing is: the SE *could* solve the problem without alienating them, why the heck they don't do? Why the heck they can't simply migrate a question asked on a bad site, or why the heck they can't convert a question, posted as an answer, to a question? Why? Why? Why??? I believe, the answer is somewhere... out of anything what we could call rational.

Comment: In my opinion, the opposite needs to be done. I'm at 69 rep (ignore the number) but after more than a year, and I'm starting to turn to other websites because I have to keep worrying whether my homework question will be closed because I'm really confused.

Comment: @ThatZ9 My impression is that you simply miss the essence of the whole discourse.

Comment: I think I was confusing, what I meant is that while your points are absoultely correct, your title is just wrong. New users should NOT require more supervision.

Comment: @ThatZ9 Please explain what the first posts review queue is for.

Answer (score -28):

My reaction? "I told you so."

**Invert the idea of creating a site where "bad" questions are filtered out.** Eliminate down votes and close votes. Retain everything. Migrate or tag the "good" questions to a "good question museum" for those who still care about that sort of thing. Even upvotes are only good for ensnaring users who didn't get the memo that gamification is *so* 2015. Google's page rankings are more effective than votes at identifying useful questions.

The "hordes of desperate help vampires" have more claim to being the SO community than do the ideologues of meta. And who knows, some of the new users you're driving off with down votes and close votes might someday be interested in contributing to your little museum.

Comment: If you see profit in maintainining a site with only bad questions (and, presumably but highly likely) likewise answers, I suggest you to invest in that.

Comment: I didn't sign up for a forum.  I abandoned forums years ago.

Comment: @usr2564301 I see a profit in maintaining a site with a higher percentage of bad questions in order to attract a higher absolute number of good questions that can be selected for curation.

Comment: Have you done any curation?

Comment: As I've seen your voting score, I've deeply felt, that it would be insightful. And so is it. I am close to think that the post scores should be interpreted negated on the MSO.

Comment: @Scratte Yes. I've been on SO since its first year, and my main account is around 9K rep. But I no longer waste my time reviewing edits or anything. I've watched a handful of bullies maintain a fake consensus about the site's purpose by driving away new users with different visions who would otherwise become a majority and overwhelm them.

Comment: It's hard enough to find good questions as it is, and you want to make that even worse?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Not at all. If you're not interested in helping new users, you could choose to browse only the museum Q&As.

Comment: @StackOverthrow And who is going to maintain that museum? Who is going to wade through the ever-growing sea of crap to find the few gems?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The same people who are currently wading through it and downvoting and closing everything in sight. They would simply be marking things as good, not bad.

Comment: @StackOverthrow And those people are *already* being driven away by SE's "friendliness" policies. Your suggestion would only accelerate it. If you want this site to turn into Yahoo Answers, just go ask your questions there instead.

Comment: Google's page rankings no longer work. Most search results are now so noisy (filled with low-quality questions) that it takes much, much longer than needed to find answers by using Stack Overflow as a research tool.

Comment: A ranking [by view rate](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120902/highest-view-rate-questions-non-community-wiki-4) would be useful, but I don't think there is a way to do that with search engines.

Comment: I support the split (whatever it is called - [Stack Overflow Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) / [Stack Overflow Professionals](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), Stack Overflow Helpdesk / Stack Overclopia). We are already in a situation where Stack Overflow is effectively a help desk (as the barrier to entry is too low (no proof of work is required and downvotes are ineffective)). By having two different domains the Google search problem is solved (use `site:stackoverclopia.com` in Google searches). It could even be two different views, but exported to different domains.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Overclopia? Is that meant to be a portmanteau of Overflow and Encyclopedia?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, I agree at this point. Personally I'd be happy to contribute to both sites, but I'm not very interested in contributing to this Franken-site that does neither one particularly well and wastes a lot of effort. Splitting seems great to me, the helpdesk site gets the "user registration" numbers up, and the encyclopedia gets the "page views" and "credibility" numbers up. IMO this might not happen unless an independent site creates both of these though, SE seems to instead be applying the wrong metrics (e.g., user registrations or number of new pages on wikipedia).

Comment: Also, I'm surprised nobody saw this coming, everybody was saying for years about "The Eternal September" -- when a site gets bigger and beyond the early adopters, it'd be just a matter of time. SO has a big "Ask Question" button, it's a famous site, it has a bad search engine, and has a reputation for experts who are willing to answer. People will just ask whatever's on their mind. I think it's too late to correct that perception now, have "Stack Overflow" be "anything goes / temporary Q/A" and have a different mechanism to contribute to the "library".