# How to discourage rushed answers on questions that should be closed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, closed-questions

Let me start by saying: I am in full favor of rewarding volunteers using (one or two) "trust points", when they perform the vital service of closing questions that should be legitimately closed.  [It's time to reward the duplicate finders](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048/2943403)

However, that would only focus on half of the glaring problem of unnecessary site bloat -- question askers.  Yes, there are questions that don't need to remain in the Stack Overflow vault, but there are volunteers, new & experienced, that are contributing to the bloat too -- question answerers.

The following is my recommendation to discourage the answering of close-worthy questions which will go a long way to help the roomba to maintain the Stack Overflow and allow volunteers to focus on better quality questions and more meaningful tasks.

### For simplicity, I will supply just two levels of infraction penalty, but the pattern can be extended if/as needed:

1. **Fresh Question Throttling Level 1 - 3 Hour (L1)** - you may not answer a question that is under 3 hours old; all question older than 3 hours are completely fair game.  In other words, you can interact with ANY question that has been posted under 3 hours ago in ANY way EXCEPT posting an answer.  You can vote, you can edit, you can flag, you can comment; you just cannot post an answer.
2. **Fresh Question Throttling Level 2 - 1 Day (L2)** - all the same rules, just 21 hours longer.

### How does a user qualify for such automated grooming?

1. By default, a user who has not yet answered 4 questions will be placed into **L1** throttling.
2. A user whose last 3 out of 4 answers have been on questions that have been closed (for any reason) will be placed into **L1** throttling.
3. A user who was already in L1 throttling and 6 of their last 8 answers have been on questions which have been closed (for any reason) will be placed into **L2** throttling.

### What does this accomplish?

- This prevents new users from answering until the wider community has had ample time to make informed decisions on the viability of the question.
- This **directly** puts a stop to Fastest Gun in the West answers who make no effort to close questions that should be closed.

### Why do I think that this is "Firm but Fair" / "Meaningful without being Mean"?

- Nearly 100% of all low-rep users will have absolutely no knowledge of the benefits/importance of closing versus answering.  Other users who can distinguish good questions from close-able questions will get the time to make this determination.
- We've all seen it. A FGITW user rushes a code-only solution to a basic duplicate question in the first 90 seconds, then the Upvote Pixies heap on the rep points for *assumed* correctness, the answerer sees that lovely green at the top of the screen and repeats the behavior as feverishly as they can.  It is my experience that Upvote Pixies do not use the "recently active" question filtering and answers that are posted hours later NEVER get the same amount of reward as the FGITW answers.  FGITW users come in a variety of rep levels -- this is an unbiased grooming imposed on 1-reppers and 300K-reppers.
- This throttling does NOT stop anyone from posting answers.  There are literally millions of questions to answer at any given moment.  This initiative only prevents posting on the very freshest of questions.
- When a user with more than 4 answers is placed in L1 or L2 throttling, they will be able to review their most recent answers to see how the page was closed.  This will allow them to reflect on their own behavior and adjust to become a better contributor (or even flag/vote to reopen if they can / wish to) (or they may even wish to delete their answer and transfer it to the earlier question if it is appropriate/unique there).
- This will prevent the heartbreak in cases where volunteers with good intentions craft a generous answer to a duplicate question that should have been closed, then the page is deleted and that answerer feels that they have wasted their time.  Grooming them to differentiate between good and bad questions will prevent this.  For those with access, I have an answer in the Stack Moderators site with the heading "Answering a good question well" which began my thinking on this proposal.
- I have erred on the side of being too loose with what qualifies a user for throttling. It *should* be rather hard to have 3 of your last 4 answers be on closed questions.
- If you go from L1 to L2 throttling, then geez, you really aren't getting the idea.  Again, this gives the community more time to close the questions that you are answering and rewards you less for answering close-able questions ...until your question selection improves and your throttling is automatically lifted by answering less-fresh questions.

I have more to say about this proposal, but nobody likes my wall-of-text posts.  I will try to reply to all answers and comments when my work/family requirements allow me.

I would like to receive answers to this question that:

- identify vulnerabilities (how users will try to game/circumvent this feature)
- positive/negative ramifications on the community/content
- suggested refinements which would make this proposal more likely to be successful/implemented

Comment: then you need also a rule that high rep users can't answer the first three hours too, so that others can also get the chance to answer a question.

Comment: Anyone who has answered more than 4 questions can post answers immediately.  This gives no unfair advantage to high-rep users. @nbk  This, in fact, is partly designed to stop high-rep users from answering questions that should be closed too.

Comment: @mickmackusa No, but what about all the users who just made a new account, they're essentially given  a handicap when they're *already* complaining about how hard it is to get reputation

Comment: New accounts will have access to literally millions of questions which can be answered.  We don't trust them to comment or vote.  This extends that same "lack of trust" to answering as well without actually stopping them entirely.  They can just as easily earn rep and help people -- on questions that should have been properly vetted by more experienced users within the first 3 hours.

Comment: But then aren't you just encouraging bad, spammy, copy-pasta answers on ancient questions so that people can get past the threshold? There would be need to some way to encourage *novel* answers to old questions, while discouraging posting junk.

Comment: If you think that that is a possible outcome, then I will encourage you to post an answer and state that you feel this is a possible negative effect.  However, I don't believe that this will be the effect.  In fact, because the "race" to be the fastest gun is eliminated by the 3hr hold, users will be able to take their time and craft with quality instead of speed. @Nick  If people are posting low-quality content, their stuff will be less likely to be useful the OP/researchers and therefore will not produce rep gains (since the post will be out of Upvote Pixie sprinkle range).

Comment: Furthermore, think about this case... A new user posts 4 new answers to questions which are not closed.  Maybe they gain zero upvotes.  Oh well, this happens, but now suddenly they have instantly/automatically unlocked the ability to answer the freshest questions.  Mission accomplished -- they answered "good questions", they now know what good questions look like, we can extend some trust and allow them to answer fresh questions.  This ability can be swiftly taken away if they prove that they cannot be trusted to identify good questions.  It is a beautiful check-n-balance, me thinks.

Comment: the main problem is that the close review is huge and nobody in their right mind , want to deal with it. A ban for having another opinion "or being not helpful" didn't encourage people, that wasn't behind the review system, to do the work. So a reform of the review system,no more bans, except when it is much much too bad. and until somebidy does the deed. and clear the close review, nothing will change

Comment: I can't follow much of that last comment @nbk But we can't sit and wait for some miracle to come along and clear the entire close vote queue.  We need to work smarter and eliminate work that can be appropriately handled in mass by fewer knowledge volunteers.  I feel overwhelmed by the constant waves of duplicate and off-topic content being posted and preserved here.  I am not giving up, I just want to be more helpful.  Those of us that care deeply about this place want to see it get better.  This is my intention.   If it needs reshaping, I am open to that.

Comment: as i said in my comment, we users will not clear that revue queue it must be done by the moderators. it boils down to this, i can't review without having a different opinion on the matter, ergo i make decisions in a review *that are not helpful*,because a moderator decides otherwise. So as long as reviewing is that bad and punishable by bans, noboday in their right mind, will do that time consuming "work"

Comment: Your concern over the volume in the Close Review Queue is a valid one and it has been this way for a long time. My suggestion is a step toward tackling this problem.  By bringing awareness that close-able questions should be closed instead of answering, users will be casting more flags and votes to close -- this will bring more helping hands to the workload in the queue. Since it only take 3 votes now, the community can be more proactive about finishing off posts with  1 or 2 votes. It seems you have some strange opinion that reviewing will get you banned; you need to get some clarity on this.

Comment: People often come for help for an immediate issue that stops all progress so desperate enough to ask SO. New user asks a Q, get immediately down-voted, edited for formatting&language (sometimes completely changing the original meaning) and then closed as a dupe. If pure intention-ed users see a brand new user with no previous questions just wanting actual help, it's being nice to post a human written thing (I'm fine with Q being deleted shortly after+no rep awarded, DRY/protect SEO). Lack of kind human interaction makes SO scary, the goal is a pure wiki, but helping others is also a goal.

Comment: Nothing about what I am suggesting is going to stop OPs from receiving an answer immediately.  I am not suggesting the throttling of questions or askers.  My recommendation is about grooming answerers to consider the the community first and take the most appropriate action prior to slapping an answer on a page that should not be answered (according to the list of close reasons).  I am not addressing voting or editing behaviors.  I am not asking anyone to be less human.  I am trying to help SO to groom new and problem answerers so that they learn how to best help this community. @ono2012

Comment: If a user answers a question and that question gets closed it's an indication that the answerer *used SO incorrectly* - isn't it? Shouldn't they have looked for a duplicate instead of answering? At the moment there is no penalty for answerers like the one in this example; that's why I like mickmackusa's proposition.

Comment: When I was a new user, I really needed the chance to fast-answer a few questions. Problem: low rep can't write comments. Older unanswered questions often require some form of clarification. If new users (who can't write comments) can't answer for 3 hours, all easy answerable questions will be gone.

Comment: @grek if an old question needs some form of clarification, then you should not be answering anyhow -- you should be flagging/voting to close. Low-rep users are asked to focus on clear questions until they can comment.  No one ever _needs_ to "fast-answer a few questions", ever.  Finally, there will ALWAYS be millions of questions that volunteers can answer.  This proposed feature never denies people based on rep; it is a direct consequence of their decision to post answers on too many questions which should have been closed instead.

Comment: @mickmackusa oh sorry, you are right, I somehow linked the "answered 4 questions" requirement to rep even though it is unrelated. So new users could dump a few bad answers to good old questions, get down-voted and still aquire the right to answer new questions as long as the answers are not deleted. Honestly, I would feel better if the proposal focused on consequences for past bad actions - ignore the "new user" handling.

Answer (score 17):

I have a couple of problems with this proposal, but the biggest is that it heavily relies on questions getting closed quickly. Let's face it, that's not the world we live in here. With the Close-Vote queue currently at 5.8k items needing review at the time of this writing, this is certainly better than before the 3 vote threshold change but not good enough to do what you're asking.

What if I answer some bad questions and for whatever reason it takes 3 days to get them closed. In the mean time, I can keep answering when in reality I should be throttled. This system has been ineffective.

Then there's the opposite case: what if a question gets closed incorrectly? Especially since your system allows closing for any reason (particularly duplicates) now I've been punished for something that I didn't even do wrong. The community was wrong.

Then there's the admittedly rare case where a question gets closed edited, and then on-topic and opened again. What do we do with cases like that? Again, this is relatively rare but is an edge case worth considering here. What implications does this have for the person being throttled here? Is the that the throttled person would be affected fair?

Really, I don't think the Close-Vote system is reliable and effective enough at this point for this to be fair and reliable either.

---

The penalty here also seems little harsh. To put Level 2 throttling in perspective, in my favorite tag of C++, I have to scroll back 5 pages to find a question 24 hours old. 5 pages at 50 items a piece of things that I have no shot at answering. Good and bad questions. And that's just the C++ tag alone.

This seemingly insurmountable of unanswerable questions will no doubt discourage people from answering at all. That kind of goes against the philosophy of Stack Overflow. It is my understanding that Stack Overflow is geared to *encourage* answers. The idea being that while questions can be useful, answers are usually a lot more useful than questions and have a lot longer lasting value. Thus, we encourage them. This system would do the opposite of that.

---

> This prevents new users from answering until the wider community has had ample time to make informed decisions on the viability of the question.

I know your intention is good here, but a system that disproportionately blocks new users from answering is not a good idea. Stack Overflow already has a perception by some that it is elitist. Critics say that only the elite can participate on Stack Overflow. I personally disagree with this, but some people do think this.

I say all this because what do you think this system will do? Will it not support this image of elitism? Regardless of your intentions, this will be received as making it easier for the elite to block out new users. I don't think that would be a good thing.

---

So, in short, I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: I am not finished reading your answer, but in the first paragraph.... no, this doesn't rely on questions being closed quickly.  It attempts to encourage the closing of questions instead of answering.  You may answer a question today, but it isn't identified as a duplicate for a week.  No matter when it is closed, if it is one of your most recent 4 answers, it goes toward the tally.  ...reading more of your answer now.

Comment: If a page is "incorrectly" closed, then you become aware (otherwise you wouldn't know) and you can become an active participant in garnering support for the question being reopened.  ...stilll reading.

Comment: @mickmackusa Majority of answerers do not have the privilege to vote to close, and many do not even have the privilege to flag for closure. We can't teach them to do something they have no privilege of doing yet.

Comment: That's true.  @Dharman  That's why those with the privilege need more time to do their vital work.

Comment: @Chipster  If a page is closed, then edited, then reopened -- AWESOME -- mission accomplished.  The OP is happier, SO is happier with on-topic content, the answerer gets one tally taken off their count.  This is an ideal win.

Comment: @mickmackusa I mention a case where a question doesn't get closed for a week (or actually, 3 days in my example). This will allow a user to keep answering anyway, likely putting them past the 4 question mark. The fact that that question was later closed is now irrelevant. For this to work, you need the questions closed really fast before the user can keep answering.

Comment: @mickmackusa The problem is that whole process potentially barred a user who answered before the closure from answering other questions in the mean time. Was it right to do this?

Comment: Okay, Chipster, this solution will not be effective in 100% of cases.  No proposed solution on meta is ever going to be 100% effective.  If you like, the tally to post ratio can be tweaked to catch high volume posters -- if 10 of their last 20 posts are on closed questions throttle them.

Comment: Again, no one is "barred" from answering -- ever.  It is just a means of excluding their participation on the freshest questions.  They can help thousands of people as much as they like while being on L1 or L2.  Nobody is ever "benched".

Comment: Yes, Level 2 is purposely harsh.  If 75% of the content that you are adding to Stack Overflow is on pages that should have been closed instead, you are not behaving as an ideal SO citizen.  We need to take steps to better groom your behavior and educate you about what is and is not a good question.

Comment: "_a system that disproportionately blocks new users from answering_" this is not what is happening here.  New users are never blocked from answering -- they will always have millions of questions where they can add meaningful content to the Stack Overflow knowledge stores.  Stack Overflow already has a number of purposeful limitations that are imposed upon new users until they prove themselves to be trustworthy.  This is just an extension of that.  This is an initiative that simplifies the focus of new users.  They won't be expected to assess question quality before answering.

Comment: My rules were specifically designed to remove any whiff of "elitism" or protection of veteran users.  I see a shocking amount of "trusted" users who repeatedly answer closeable questions without pausing for a second to consider if the question should be closed.  Currently, you cannot stop them for role modeling this unwanted behavior.  Downvotes do not phase them because points no longer matter to them and the Upvote Pixies neutralize them anyhow. My suggestion is deliberately structured to have an equal impact on users of any rep level.  Nobody is immune to this grooming.

Comment: The fact that some veteran volunteers have ready-made comments to inform users about closing instead of answering means that there is a long-standing problem to address.  e.g. **"_Please don't answer duplicate questions. Instead, flag or vote for them to be closed as a duplicate. If you feel your answer adds an additional approach to those which are on the duplicate-target question (linked at the top of the page), then it's *far* better to create an answer on the duplicate-target where it will be seen by many more people and, probably, get significantly more upvotes._"**

Comment: "a system that disproportionately blocks new users" - I think the effect could potentially be worse (or similarly bad) for more experienced users that don't care so much about whether questions are on topic (especially those with 10k+ or 100k+ reputation). Getting blocked *once* could kill someone's motivation to contribute altogether. Overall it would likely make a huge dent in the number of answerers without decreasing the number of questions. That would decrease the percentage of questions that get answered and probably push away people with good questions.

Comment: ... In an ideal world this would result in only the bad questions receiving fewer answers, or at least this would start happening eventually. But realistically the unanswered questions will probably be more random as there are just be too many questions to process all of them (and answerers may avoid useful, but more borderline, questions), good contributors may lose interest before the site recovers and bad contributors tend to be more persistent.

Comment: @Dukeling High rep users answering obvious duplicates know they shouldn't. Allowing abuse because they contribute in other ways is to enable abuse which is to abuse & is never appropriate.

Comment: @philipxy Calling it abuse is probably a bit extreme. While plenty of people have complained about users answering bad questions, I don't think I've ever seen an official stance clearly saying answers to such questions are not acceptable. Or, if we say the community defines the rules, it's probably generally allowed if we go by how it's usually received. At worst it's something some of us don't like. Maybe it makes logical sense to condemn answers encouraging bad questions, but neither the community nor the staff is doing this. Thus, by definition, such answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 9):

There *is already* a system for discouraging answers to low-quality and/or duplicate questions: it's called **downvoting**.

So, let's say somebody posts such an answer, looking for some quick Mermaid Points; they get an "Accept" and one up-vote, giving them +25 rep. It only takes *13 downvotes* to reverse that reputation gain! (Sounds like a lot of votes, but I've seen the "Meta Effect" achieve that sort of outcome in *minutes*!)

However, long before the nett *reputation* score goes negative, the answer (or, more likely, the question) will become eligible for deletion (as it's *vote* score will go negative); and, if I understand the system correctly, reputation gained on an answer that is subsequently deleted will be lost, unless it has an overall *vote* score of +3 or more, and has been on the site for 90 days before deletion.

Comment: *"will become eligible for deletion"*... sure, but that doesn't mean it will actually be deleted.

Comment: @Nick Indeed not. However, there are ways to bring such deletion-eligible posts to the attention of that part of the community that actively participates in such curation. (SOCVR chatroom springs to mind, where the OP is active).

Comment: Yes, SOCVR can delete *some* answers, but not enough to counter this, on top of that, there are even people (at least one) who frequent SOCVR that post answers to blatant dupes, there would need to be a more conscious effort from a larger group of people for it to be effective.

Comment: Sentence 1: Downvoting questions does very little to halt the generation of unwanted content from getting stored long-term on SO.  Paragraph 2: I have been here for years and invested thousands of volunteer hours to this place and I have **never once** seen an upvoted and accepted answer later receiving 13 DVs.  I find that statement to be too far removed from reality to be considered part of the conversation that I am trying to have.

Comment: Paragraph 3: pages can be deleted after the question has been closed and after some time has passed or if the Q is < -3.  All this extra effort to remove pages with answers means more human work which would be better spent doing other things.

Comment: This only works for particularly low quality questions or answers. There are simply too many people upvoting such answers and the questions often don't end up getting deleted.

Comment: But many of the answers to dupes are posted in 'good faith', or 'in error' (I've done it myself - but less and less often as I gain experience with the site). These can actually be good answers, and shouldn't be downvoted or deleted. The 'habitual dupe-answerers' are only a fraction of the total (but, I agree, a *significant* fraction).

Comment: @Dukeling It's difficult to stop folks upvoting, I know, but a few downvote 'hits' on answers from the habitual offenders may well serve the purpose in discouraging repeat behaviour.

Comment: @AdrianMole It's true that people who would otherwise vote to close may post an answer if they don't know it's a duplicate, and that's fine. But I think a lot of people just don't care about moderation at all. They see a question, they answer it. I don't really even *want* to downvote such people, because I don't believe that's an effective way to get them to *start* caring about moderation and people frequently counter such downvotes with upvotes. Meaning it mostly just makes everyone more negative, creates a bigger divide in the community and the downvoter is the only one losing reputation.

Comment: I started off just posting answers to anything and everything. I did see the light eventually, but if I were to have gotten a downvote or rude comment on every second answer, I probably would've just stopped contributing altogether. If someone had instead left a gentle comment bringing to my attention that the question was an obvious duplicate and linking to somewhere that discusses why we close things in general or as duplicates, this may have helped me get there sooner. Although this mostly applies to some new users. More experienced users have likely already had all their revelations.

Answer (score 6):

I like this idea, but I do not think it is going to work out, which makes it a bad idea in my opinion. I see too many problems with this proposal, but despite that, I love that you are trying to solve this problem. Maybe this is not the way to solve it, but I think we need to admit that Stack Overflow does have a problem with answers.

Moderators can already suspend people for low quality contributions. The system automatically bans people from posting low quality answers if they have posted too many poor answers. See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/515960) We already have a system in place to prevent serial offenders from contributing more garbage.

## Why is fresh-question throttling a bad idea?

When you look at answers being posted, a lot of them are being added to questions which are already at least a day old. If you only want to prevent FGITW then you are missing a bunch of low quality answers on older questions. What should we do to stop that? Also, if you prevent users from answering the fresh questions, and they really want to build up their reputation points, then you are only forcing them to post low quality answers on older questions. You merely shift the problem elsewhere.

## About closing questions.

> This prevents new users from answering until the wider community has had ample time to make informed decisions on the viability of the question.

There are many more potential answerers than there are users with close vote privileges to decide if the question is good or bad. Obviously new users do not have the experience necessary to judge which questions are good and which are not (this is why we do not let them to flag/vote for closure). Why should we punish them for answering questions if they do not know any better? We want them to get the reputation needed to close questions and learn how to contribute well to this site. The best way to do so is to encourage them to answer the available questions. I do not think preventing or discouraging new users from answering is a good idea.

## What about established users who choose to answer the question, which should be closed.

Well, this one is a difficult one. I know of users who are contributing in a lot of ways and I admire their comments, their edits and the fact that they close a lot of questions. Yet, from time to time I still see them answering poor questions, which I believe should be closed and deleted as soon as possible.

People's opinions differ. For example, I can see value in answering a question and you might think it's useless. But this is why we need 3 people to close and 3 people to vote to delete. You are however free to express your opinions by voting on every post. If you think the contribution is not useful, you can downvote.

If you personally think that the question should be closed, then vote to close. If you think the question adds nothing to the site, then vote to delete. But you still need at least two people to agree with you.

## Answers can save a question!

Questions are less important than answers in my opinion. If someone posts a poorly worded question, we can edit it to make it better. Sometimes, we might not see any value in a badly written question, but a user might still write a really good answer. If the answer is good and becomes popular then someone will eventually edit the question to make it better and the whole topic is saved. Question is just a means for answers to appear.

> This will prevent the heartbreak in cases where volunteers with good intentions craft a generous answer to a duplicate question that should have been closed, then the page is deleted and that answerer feels that they have wasted their time.

That should not take place in principle. If someone poured their heart into writing a good answer which was well acclaimed by others, then why would we delete the question? That is just hurtful to the person who posted the answer. Clearly, **the question was answerable and it attracted good answer.** That question should be edited and kept, because of its answers.

Remember, we do not need to close all questions, just the ones which attract bad answers. Quite often answers are the measure of the question's quality.

## What can we do to prevent the accumulation of bad answers?

If a question is attracting poor answers, and you yourself can't write a better answer or even imagine how one would come up with a better answer, then the question needs to be closed. If you feel powerless with your one vote, you can ask SOCVR to take a second look, confirm the question needs to be closed and help you close it.

If the question is closed and no one upvotes either question or answers nor does any answer get accepted, then the system will remove such question. If the question received upvotes or has accepted answer, and you see that the answers are not useful and the question cannot be salvaged, then you can cast your delete vote. A good measure for how valuable the contributions are is often the rating and the views. Don't be fooled by these, because often bad answers get a lot of upvotes. In such cases, it is best to use your best judgement to decide if keeping such thread will cause more harm to the community then good. If so, we should delete such upvoted posts. Of course, try as much as possible to salvage the content. If the answer was on the right track, but they made a lot of mistakes, then fix these mistakes for them. Do not trash the whole thing if you can edit and make it a good contribution.

## What is the problem with answers then?

There are a few problems. For one, we do get a lot of answers which are *not an answer*. Most of them are found by our bots and flagged automatically or flagged by avid followers of these bots. The system could be improved to do the same. Flag them automatically or even better prevent such answers. If we can easily write a simple bot to do it, then Stack Overflow should be much more capable of implementing this into the product.

Secondly, new users rush into answering spree. I am not sure if there is something to limit their eagerness, but I think there should be something. It makes it more difficult to clean up their answers if they post them like a machine gun. Recently I have seen a few users between them posting a few hundred answers which were very low quality. I can't flag them, because such flags get declined and it seems like there is nothing I can do to slow them down. I can't even review each answer one by one and see if maybe the question they answered should be closed or their answer downvoted, because this is user targeting.

Lastly, we need something to educate new users on how to judge which question should be answered and which should not be answered. This will prepare them for the time when they can start flagging questions. We also need to encourage long-time users to contribute more to the site by a way of closing questions. We need people to be able to and want to act on these flags. I would love to go through the close review queue, but my own tag is such a queue in itself. I can't handle flags in the queue if I use up all my close votes scrolling through the newest questions in my tag.

Comment: This suggestion was never going to be a golden beam of light to vanquish all low-quality answers from touching this community.  It is meant to be a step in the right direction.  It is part of a larger scheme to gradually groom users to understand the kind of top-quality content that SO is trying to curate.  "_then you are only forcing them to post low quality answers on older questions_" No, no I am not.  I am actually taking away the unsavory part of posting which fundamentally leads to lower quality -- Speed Posting.

Comment: "_Obviously new users do not have the experience necessary to judge which questions are good and which are not_" I do like the agreement throughout this page that admits that new users lack the ability accurately/consistently distinguish good questions from bad.  Admitting this is certainly the first step toward needing a solution such as mine to set new users to the side until new questions have been vetted or until the new user has been considered trustworthy.

Comment: The "punishment" of not being able to answer fresh questions is only maintained until they have proved themselves to be trustworthy.  We currently have the exact same systematic approach to all other earned privileges (commenting, flagging, voting, etc).  My suggestion is in no way different from withholding access to certain aspects of this site until deemed appropriate.

Comment: Even if answers from new users are low-quality, at least they are on pages that are worth toiling on in the hope of curating good content. We can continue to use all of the regular tools to tend to answers that need our intervention. In the end, we have a good foundation/question which volunteers can  confidently contribute to.  Conversely, when we have good or bad answers on bad questions, then SO suffers from sticky bad content that should have been purged from the very beginning.  "Sticky" because the roomba won't clear the page and volunteers must manually/slowly remove the low value page.

Comment: "_Questions are less important than answers in my opinion._" I respectfully disagree.  Without questions there can be no answers.  Which you eventuslly agree with.    What we will probably also agree on is that the better the question, the better the answers can be.  Ultimately, if a question isn't complete, then it can be closed as needing details.  This isn't a "go away" vote, this is a fix this up so that we can help you properly.  "_the question was answerable_" this is not the only criteria for assessing a question. Thousands of answerable questions are duplicates.

Comment: There is no way of stopping high-volume low-quality answerers. The good news about what I am suggesting is that if they are answering close-able questions, then they will go to L1. While in L1 they will invariably get "paid less" for their high-volume answering.  This is probably the best that we can do, for now, while maintaining relative freedom for all other contributors.  While low-value answers are getting sprinkled by the Upvote Pixies, your appropriate DVs are going to be (irritatingly) neutralized.  By pushing these posters outside of the pixie zone, you have a better shot at grooming.

Comment: "_Remember, we do not need to close all questions, just the ones which attract bad answers._"  I disagree here too.  A duplicate question can attract a good answer, but it should indeed be closed.

Comment: How about instead of "Answers can save a question", we say that "**Answerers** can save a question".  If a question is _nearly_ good enough to keep open and on SO, then giving answerers some extrinsic motivation to improve question quality is a good thing.  If those who answer learned that they would have an easier UX by improving/defending questions to be "worth retaining on SO", then I think we would find more better questions retained and fewer bad questions answered.  This means more _organic_ curation.

Comment: The first objection (that it only fixes FGITW, not bad answers in general) is a specious argument.  It boils down to "we can't achieve perfection so we shouldn't do anything to try to improve any part of the situation".  Any real-world approach (like this or completely different) is going to be about making a statistical improvement, not preventing every bad answer to every question that should have been closed.  (Or reducing the rate at which such Qs are asked).

Comment: This proposal *does* have problems, e.g. maybe frustrating and driving away some existing contributors who are overall a net positive, and maybe turning away some new users who could have become valuable members.  But only addressing FGITW is not one of those problems.