# Add a delay for closing / deleting questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close

Today I experienced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493382/can-you-explain-me-the-code-im-not-getting-the-yield-part-what-a0-and-a1) on SO get closed in 17 minutes as a duplicate. The part about what yield does is a duplicate, yes, but as I wrote in the comments there are other problems the OP obviously did not notice (in fact, they are hard, or even impossible, to spot for a beginner in Python), and I was not able to provide an answer pointing out these problems, because, as I was almost done writing my answer, the question got closed ! So not only the OP will probably never know why the code does not do what he expects, but I had invested time for nothing, too ! That's why I think it should be impossible (or only possible for moderators) to close new questions for some hours (e.g. 12). Then, if no one has answered in that delay, it could always be closed.

It could even go as far as, let the users vote for closing the question, but not delete it directly. Instead, only close it when the delay is over and no one has answered.

Comment: Try to invest time on better questions instead. Also, don't answer too broad questions.

Comment: And closing questions is **expressly meant to stop answers from being posted**. There are already 76 answers to the duplicate post (including deleted posts), we don't need more posts on the subject.

Comment: I can see an argument for having a delay before *deleting* a question, but one of the main reasons for closing questions soon is to prevent low quality answers (guesses, etc) from coming in. I don't think having a delay to close is a good idea.

Comment: What you're suggesting would potentially just have multiple people waste their time if in the end the question would get closed anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ___76 Answers?!___ Geez... Perhaps a cleanup is in order...

Comment: I mean, there's a lot of correct information in there, but also a ___lot___ of redundancy... I'm pretty sure you can delete all but the top ~5 scoring answers there and basically not lose any actual information

Comment: @Cerbrus: that's including 36 deleted posts.

Comment: 40 answers is still waaaaaaay too many.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I go through them from time to time. I'll do so again now, I've found some plagiarism already. Now down to 38 visible answers.

Comment: Please see [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/4642212). If you disagree with closure as duplicate, the proper response is to edit your post and explain exactly what is different and why. Asserting that it just _is_ different is not enough. See [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476/289905), ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](/q/252252/4642212).

Comment: Also read [Question closed while composing an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40877/289905).

Comment: Were the other problems related to OPs question how yield works? If not, then why write an answer about that? A comment would be the better choice (in my point of view) to not distract from the actual question.

Comment: Don't lump closure and deletion together. They are two different processes and what is true for one is not true for the other. You are talking about closure specifically here.

Comment: 17min is too slow .. come one we need faster!

Comment: Maybe there should be a delay on *answering* questions to give people a chance to close them.

Comment: @khelwood - this was [proposed before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397526/11407695), not very well received either (not judging the merits here, only linking to the discussion)

Comment: Close it--No [mre]. They need to show the first point of the execution where the state is not what they can justify is correct by referencing authoritative documentation, for the least code that they show is correct code minimally extended by wrong code. Otherwise they are just dumping a pile of code they don't understand & are lost in for others to debug,

Answer (score 28):

We close posts **explicitly to block answers being posted**. Delaying closing defeats that purpose.

If we were to delay closing, and so let answers be posted, people that post bad questions would not have any incentive to improve their questions to fit the mission of Stack Overflow: for their questions to be useful for *future visitors*. **We serve the user that Google's their question before posting here, more than we serve those that post without searching.**

The example question you linked to has already been answered, with some great posts, in the duplicate target. If you have a better answer than posted there, you can add it *there*. Just be mindful there are already 79 answers posted to that question (including 41 deleted posts), so make sure *your* answer addresses things the other remaining 38 visible answers do not. Remember, you want to help not just the person asking the question, but everyone else that arrives there after searching for how Python's `yield` expression works.

Note that the specific question was also *too broad*. We do not, as a rule, accept questions that ask to explain that much code without further context as to what they do and don't understand. That's not useful for future visitors. If the post had not been closed as a duplicate it shoud have been closed for that reason, anyway. Perhaps you need to find better questions to answer?

Comment: This answer is a good answer on the yield part, but it does not address that there are other problems in his code which can only be spotted at all by an advanced Python programmer. (Did you find them ??? :D)

Comment: @Programmer: that's not the goal of that question.

Comment: I do not understand why this should not be the goal of the question.

Comment: @Programmer: did they ask, specifically, about problems with the code?

Comment: No, they did not. So ?

Comment: @Programmer: so, that makes the post not suitable for this site. The point of _Stack Overflow_ is that questions and their answers are useful for other people too. You do that by keeping the question clear and focused and explicit.